# 'console' is undefined error for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

I'm using Firebug and have some statements like:

```
console.log("...");
```

in my page. In IE8 (probably earlier versions too) I get script errors saying 'console' is undefined. I tried putting this at the top of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (!console) console = {log: function() {}};
</script>
```

still I get the errors. Any way to get rid of the errors?

Comment: Use `typeof` in your if, it will avoid undefined errors:  
    `if(typeof console === "undefined") {
    var console = { log: function (logMsg) { } };
    }`

Comment: console.log() only works when IE's dev tool is open (yes IE is crappy). see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once

Comment: Best answer to that question is http://stackoverflow.com/a/16916941/2274855

Comment: see https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/js/plugins.js

Comment: @Aprillion link is broken, use this one instead: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/js/plugins.js

Comment: Using console logging in production is a bad idea anyway, at least a code smell. You might, by accident, expose sensitive user data. I use Sonar to detect any `console.log` statements, and force me to remove it before moving to production.

Comment: `if(!window.console) alert("Please use a real browser")`

Answer (score 378, accepted):

Try

```
if (!window.console) console = ...
```

An undefined variable cannot be referred directly. However, all global variables are attributes of the same name of the global context (`window` in case of browsers), and accessing an undefined attribute is fine.

Or use `if (typeof console === 'undefined') console = ...` if you want to avoid the magic variable `window`, see [@Tim Down's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3326695/).

Comment: Just to be clear to anyone else using this, place `<script type="text/javascript"> if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}}; </script>` at the top of your page! Thanks Kenny.

Comment: What about `var console = console || { log: function() {} };`

Comment: @lorddev To use that shorthand you need to include `window`: `var console = window.console || { log: function() {} };`

Comment: Damn... you build a nice website, developing it for your favorite browser. At the end you spend 4-5 HOURS making it compatible with all other MODERN browsers, and then you spend 4-5 DAYS making it compatible with IE.

Comment: The problem with that answer is if you are using another name like debug, warn, count with browser that lack console will throw a exception see the better way to do that http://stackoverflow.com/a/16916941/2274855

Comment: Just FYI, the code above posted by killianmcc simply prevents an error, but the actual `console.log()` function does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @lorddev that will only affect the local scope of console. You need to modify `window.log` to affect other script files, which fall outside the local scope.

Comment: Ugh! I would just like to say that this will only work if you own the page in question and can modify it.  This does not help if your code is in an embedded control in a 3rd party app you don't control that is starting an unknown browser beyond your control.

Answer (score 324):

Paste the following at the top of your JavaScript (before using the console):

```
/**
 * Protect window.console method calls, e.g. console is not defined on IE
 * unless dev tools are open, and IE doesn't define console.debug
 * 
 * Chrome 41.0.2272.118: debug,error,info,log,warn,dir,dirxml,table,trace,assert,count,markTimeline,profile,profileEnd,time,timeEnd,timeStamp,timeline,timelineEnd,group,groupCollapsed,groupEnd,clear
 * Firefox 37.0.1: log,info,warn,error,exception,debug,table,trace,dir,group,groupCollapsed,groupEnd,time,timeEnd,profile,profileEnd,assert,count
 * Internet Explorer 11: select,log,info,warn,error,debug,assert,time,timeEnd,timeStamp,group,groupCollapsed,groupEnd,trace,clear,dir,dirxml,count,countReset,cd
 * Safari 6.2.4: debug,error,log,info,warn,clear,dir,dirxml,table,trace,assert,count,profile,profileEnd,time,timeEnd,timeStamp,group,groupCollapsed,groupEnd
 * Opera 28.0.1750.48: debug,error,info,log,warn,dir,dirxml,table,trace,assert,count,markTimeline,profile,profileEnd,time,timeEnd,timeStamp,timeline,timelineEnd,group,groupCollapsed,groupEnd,clear
 */
(function() {
  // Union of Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera, and Safari console methods
  var methods = ["assert", "cd", "clear", "count", "countReset",
    "debug", "dir", "dirxml", "error", "exception", "group", "groupCollapsed",
    "groupEnd", "info", "log", "markTimeline", "profile", "profileEnd",
    "select", "table", "time", "timeEnd", "timeStamp", "timeline",
    "timelineEnd", "trace", "warn"];
  var length = methods.length;
  var console = (window.console = window.console || {});
  var method;
  var noop = function() {};
  while (length--) {
    method = methods[length];
    // define undefined methods as noops to prevent errors
    if (!console[method])
      console[method] = noop;
  }
})();
```

The function closure wrapper is to scope the variables as to not define any variables. This guards against both undefined `console` and undefined `console.debug` (and other missing methods).

**EDIT:** I noticed that [**HTML5 Boilerplate**](https://html5boilerplate.com/) uses similar code in its js/plugins.js file, if you're looking for a solution that will (probably) be kept up-to-date.

Comment: Why has this answer so few upvotes? It is the most complete one of the ones posted here.

Comment: Because of date. Absolutely agree with correct working solutions. I think this topic need be moderated. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Quite complete except that it will not try to redirect logging to the log function (if present) so all logs are lost

Comment: To clarify, for example, if console.debug is undefined, redirect it to console.log instead of noop?

Comment: When would this occur exactly? This code should only define elements that are not defined yet.

Comment: @honyovk that is not correct. This code doesn't override any existing methods. Instead it stubs any non-existent method on the current console implementation to do nothing when called. For example, if Firefox had a method `console.highfive()`, and Chrome didn't, this code would define `console.highfive = function() {};` so calling `console.highfive(user);` in Chrome would do nothing but would still execute as intended in Firefox. In IE, each method would be stubbed.

Comment: Also see similar solution called "firebugx.js" located here: http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.2/lite/firebugx.js?r=187

Comment: Last line should be:

}());

Comment: I think either way - (function(){...}()) or (function(){...})() - works actually

Answer (score 73):

Another alternative is the `typeof` operator:

```
if (typeof console == "undefined") {
    this.console = {log: function() {}};
}
```

Yet another alternative is to use a logging library, such as my own [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/).

Comment: It would be a good idea to change undeclared assignment into a proper declaration, though.

Comment: Do you mean using `var`? That would only confuse things here. Or do you mean assigning to `window.console` rather than `console`?

Comment: Using `var`. Why would it confuse things here?

Comment: Putting a `var` inside an `if` block is confusing and looks like a mistake. It also changes the nature of `console` regardless of whether the `if` block is executed because a variable is always declared. I agree that implicitly assigning to a global variable as I am here also looks like a mistake, but it only changes behaviour when `console` is undefined. Neither is ideal.

Comment: The problem with omitting `var` when assigning to `console` — as in this example — is not even so much that it looks like a mistake. First of all, IE DOM has an unfortunate peculiarity when undeclared assignment throws error if identifier is the same as id of one of the elements in the document. Second — and more importantly — in ES5 strict mode, undecl. assignment is actually a deliberate ReferenceError. Given that strict mode is more or less a future direction of a language, for compatibility reasons, undecl. assignments are best avoided. But if you must, `this.console=..` is an alt. option.

Comment: Re the IE DOM global scope pollution insanity, I am aware of it but we already know console is undefined, at least at the point that code is run. The ES5 point is a good one: I haven't started thinking in terms of ES5 all the time yet. For myself, I wouldn't consider using that code anyway and instead create a wrapper around console.

Comment: Hey Tim. I see you changed `console = ...` to `this.console = ...`. Excellent, I changed my vote.

Comment: Ah, right, thanks. Wondered whether it might've been you. I was waiting till we'd finished discussing before changing it; the ES5 point had clinched it, but I wasn't sure if you were still advocating `var console` over `this.console`.

Comment: Well I personally use `var console = ...` and `this.console = ...` interchangeably. Let me also point out that variable declaration does not change the nature of existing variable (or property of variable object, to be precise). If `console` is already a global property, `var console` executed in global code is essentially a no-op. That's why `if (typeof console == 'undefined') { var console = ... }` does not change `console` at all if it's already declared. Alternative version would be `var console; if (typeof console == 'undefined') { console = .. }`, but this could look confusing as well :)

Comment: OK. You're right. Obviously using `var console` would change the nature of a `console` property that was added to the global object later on, but that wasn't the point we were previously discussing. Thanks.

Comment: What a confusing discussion.  +1 to orginal answer.  If I could give +2 I would for providing a link to you own log4javascript.  Thanks OP!

Comment: Unexpected 'typeof'. Use '===' to compare directly with undefined.

Comment: @yckart: No. `typeof` is guaranteed to return a string and `"undefined"` is a string. When the two operands are of the same type, `==` and `===` are specified to perform exactly the same steps. Using `typeof x == "undefined"` is a rock-solid way to test whether `x` is undefined in any scope and any ECMAScript 3 compliant environment.

Comment: Also to be strict this should use ===. This is the only 100% strict answer supplied just saying !window.console will throw errors in some browsers. if (typeof(var) === "undefined") and use braces is the correct strict syntax for this operation.

Comment: @HughWood: `==` and `===` are precisely equivalent in this case because both operands are guaranteed to be strings, so there's no objective advantage to using `===`. Also `typeof` is an operator rather than a function so parentheses are unnecessary.

Comment: @TimDown Sorry I wasn't clear, the code isn't strict, === will make it strict and pass linting, hope that clarifies what I meant

Comment: @HughWood: Fair enough, if "strict" means "conforms to Douglas Crockford's subjective idea of good practice". Standardizing on `===` is not a bad idea, but neither is using `==` where appropriate. As you may have guessed, I find JSLint excessively opinionated.

Comment: @TimDown I think that Crockford is right this time round, but I would still like to check this vs browser interpreters on any real world differences, but this is a different thread.

Comment: @HughWood: Well, in the ECMAScript spec, the steps for `==` and `===` are precisely the same when the operands are of the same type, and no benchmark I've seen has shown any significant performance differences between them for such cases.

Answer (score 47):

For a more robust solution, use this piece of code (taken from twitter's source code):

```
// Avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console.
(function() {
    var method;
    var noop = function () {};
    var methods = [
        'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
        'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
        'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
        'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
    ];
    var length = methods.length;
    var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

    while (length--) {
        method = methods[length];

        // Only stub undefined methods.
        if (!console[method]) {
            console[method] = noop;
        }
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 13):

In my scripts, I either use the shorthand:

```
window.console && console.log(...) // only log if the function exists
```

or, if it's not possible or feasible  to edit every console.log line, I create a fake console:

```
// check to see if console exists. If not, create an empty object for it,
// then create and empty logging function which does nothing. 
//
// REMEMBER: put this before any other console.log calls
!window.console && (window.console = {} && window.console.log = function () {});
```

Comment: Syntax error. Why not just `if(!console) {console = {} ; console.log = function(){};}`

Comment: Or not just `!window.console && (window.console = { log: function () { } });`

Answer (score 9):

You can use `console.log()` if you have `Developer Tools` in IE8 opened and also you can use the `Console` textbox on script tab.

Comment: This is not good if you forget to sweap the code of console. The error in IE8 will prevent your JS code from working

Answer (score 7):

```
if (typeof console == "undefined") {
  this.console = {
    log: function() {},
    info: function() {},
    error: function() {},
    warn: function() {}
  };
}
```

Comment: caveat emptor: this should be defined at the global level where `this` refers to `window`.

Answer (score 7):

Based on two previous answers by

- [Vinícius Moraes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16916941/253468)
- [Peter Tseng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13817235/253468)

and the documentations for

- [Internet Explorer (IE 10)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772169(v=vs.85).aspx#methods)
- [Safari (2012. 07. 23.)](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH8-SW20)
- [Firefox (2013. 05. 20.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console)
- [Chrome (2013. 01. 25.)](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api) and [Chrome (2012. 10. 04.)](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/speedtracer/logging-api)
- and some of my knowledge

Here's a best effort implementation for the issue, meaning if there's a console.log which actually exists, it fills in the gaps for non-existing methods via console.log.

For example for IE6/7 you can replace logging with alert (stupid but works) and then include the below monster (I called it console.js):
[Feel free to remove comments as you see fit, I left them in for reference, a minimizer can tackle them]:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
    (window.console = window.console || {}).log = function() { return window.alert.apply(window, arguments); };
</SCRIPT>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="console.js"></script>
```

and console.js:

```
    /**
     * Protect window.console method calls, e.g. console is not defined on IE
     * unless dev tools are open, and IE doesn't define console.debug
     */
    (function() {
        var console = (window.console = window.console || {});
        var noop = function () {};
        var log = console.log || noop;
        var start = function(name) { return function(param) { log("Start " + name + ": " + param); } };
        var end = function(name) { return function(param) { log("End " + name + ": " + param); } };

        var methods = {
            // Internet Explorer (IE 10): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772169(v=vs.85).aspx#methods
            // assert(test, message, optionalParams), clear(), count(countTitle), debug(message, optionalParams), dir(value, optionalParams), dirxml(value), error(message, optionalParams), group(groupTitle), groupCollapsed(groupTitle), groupEnd([groupTitle]), info(message, optionalParams), log(message, optionalParams), msIsIndependentlyComposed(oElementNode), profile(reportName), profileEnd(), time(timerName), timeEnd(timerName), trace(), warn(message, optionalParams)
            // "assert", "clear", "count", "debug", "dir", "dirxml", "error", "group", "groupCollapsed", "groupEnd", "info", "log", "msIsIndependentlyComposed", "profile", "profileEnd", "time", "timeEnd", "trace", "warn"

            // Safari (2012. 07. 23.): https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH8-SW20
            // assert(expression, message-object), count([title]), debug([message-object]), dir(object), dirxml(node), error(message-object), group(message-object), groupEnd(), info(message-object), log(message-object), profile([title]), profileEnd([title]), time(name), markTimeline("string"), trace(), warn(message-object)
            // "assert", "count", "debug", "dir", "dirxml", "error", "group", "groupEnd", "info", "log", "profile", "profileEnd", "time", "markTimeline", "trace", "warn"

            // Firefox (2013. 05. 20.): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console
            // debug(obj1 [, obj2, ..., objN]), debug(msg [, subst1, ..., substN]), dir(object), error(obj1 [, obj2, ..., objN]), error(msg [, subst1, ..., substN]), group(), groupCollapsed(), groupEnd(), info(obj1 [, obj2, ..., objN]), info(msg [, subst1, ..., substN]), log(obj1 [, obj2, ..., objN]), log(msg [, subst1, ..., substN]), time(timerName), timeEnd(timerName), trace(), warn(obj1 [, obj2, ..., objN]), warn(msg [, subst1, ..., substN])
            // "debug", "dir", "error", "group", "groupCollapsed", "groupEnd", "info", "log", "time", "timeEnd", "trace", "warn"

            // Chrome (2013. 01. 25.): https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api
            // assert(expression, object), clear(), count(label), debug(object [, object, ...]), dir(object), dirxml(object), error(object [, object, ...]), group(object[, object, ...]), groupCollapsed(object[, object, ...]), groupEnd(), info(object [, object, ...]), log(object [, object, ...]), profile([label]), profileEnd(), time(label), timeEnd(label), timeStamp([label]), trace(), warn(object [, object, ...])
            // "assert", "clear", "count", "debug", "dir", "dirxml", "error", "group", "groupCollapsed", "groupEnd", "info", "log", "profile", "profileEnd", "time", "timeEnd", "timeStamp", "trace", "warn"
            // Chrome (2012. 10. 04.): https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/speedtracer/logging-api
            // markTimeline(String)
            // "markTimeline"

            assert: noop, clear: noop, trace: noop, count: noop, timeStamp: noop, msIsIndependentlyComposed: noop,
            debug: log, info: log, log: log, warn: log, error: log,
            dir: log, dirxml: log, markTimeline: log,
            group: start('group'), groupCollapsed: start('groupCollapsed'), groupEnd: end('group'),
            profile: start('profile'), profileEnd: end('profile'),
            time: start('time'), timeEnd: end('time')
        };

        for (var method in methods) {
            if ( methods.hasOwnProperty(method) && !(method in console) ) { // define undefined methods as best-effort methods
                console[method] = methods[method];
            }
        }
    })();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if we need `methods.hasOwnProperty(method) && ` in the for loop.

Comment: I'm sure that you do need it.

Comment: Did a quick test in Chrome's console: `> x = { a: 1, b: 2}` --> `Object {a: 1, b: 2}` and `for(var f in x) {console.log(f + " " + x[f]);} 'end'` --> `a 1 b 2 "end"`. So a created anonymous object does not have any additional property, and `methods` is just created before the `for` loop. Is it possible to hack the above?

Comment: Yes. `var x = { a: 1, b: 2}; Object.prototype.surprise = 'I\'m in yer objectz'; for (var f in x) {console.log(f, x[f]);}` You never know what a library has done to the objects in the inheritance chain of the object you're working with. Thus the recommendation by javascript code quality tools like jshint and jslint to use `hasOwnProperty`.

Answer (score 6):

In IE9, if console is not opened, this code:

```
alert(typeof console);
```

will show "object", but this code

```
alert(typeof console.log);
```

will throw TypeError exception, but not return undefined value;

So, guaranteed version of code will look similar to this:

```
try {
    if (window.console && window.console.log) {
        my_console_log = window.console.log;
    }
} catch (e) {
    my_console_log = function() {};
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I am only using console.log in my code.  So I include a very short 2 liner

```
var console = console || {};
console.log = console.log || function(){};
```

Comment: How its working.. .I'm not seeing any console.log line printed to the IE browser, i have tested with 2 different systems where in 1 - console.log is working and 2 system its not. i tried in both but not able to see any log in both the systems .

Answer (score 2):

Noticed that OP is using Firebug with IE, so assume it's [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).  This is a funky situation as console gets defined in IE when the debugger window is opened, but what happens when Firebug is already running?  Not sure, but perhaps the "firebugx.js" method might be a good way to test in this situation:

source:

https://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.2/lite/firebugx.js?r=187

```
    if (!window.console || !console.firebug) {
        var names = [
            "log", "debug", "info", "warn", "error", "assert",
            "dir","dirxml","group","groupEnd","time","timeEnd",
            "count","trace","profile","profileEnd"
        ];
        window.console = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i)
            window.console[names[i]] = function() {}
    }
```

(updated links 12/2014)

Answer (score 2):

Stub of console in TypeScript:

```
if (!window.console) {
console = {
    assert: () => undefined,
    clear: () => undefined,
    count: () => undefined,
    debug: () => undefined,
    dir: () => undefined,
    dirxml: () => undefined,
    error: () => undefined,
    group: () => undefined,
    groupCollapsed: () => undefined,
    groupEnd: () => undefined,
    info: () => undefined,
    log: () => undefined,
    msIsIndependentlyComposed: (e: Element) => false,
    profile: () => undefined,
    profileEnd: () => undefined,
    select: () => undefined,
    time: () => undefined,
    timeEnd: () => undefined,
    trace: () => undefined,
    warn: () => undefined,
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [fauxconsole](http://icant.co.uk/sandbox/fauxconsole/); I modified the css a bit so that it looks nicer but works very well.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging in IE, check out this [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/)

Comment: This is great, especially as my IE8 console doesn't output anything.

Comment: I was looking for the comment on another question here that said 'shameless self promotion' or I don't know - similar - someone who said he created this scipt, was it you? I already closed that tab. Anyway it's a really great tool and very useful for my project.

Comment: @Firsh I didn't created this script, I am a person like you benefited using tool.

Answer (score 1):

For IE8 or console support limited to console.log (no debug, trace, ...) you can do the following:

- If console OR console.log undefined: Create dummy functions for
  console functions (trace, debug, log, ...)

  `window.console = {
        debug : function() {}, ...};`
- Else if console.log is defined (IE8) AND console.debug (any other) is not defined: redirect all logging functions to console.log, this allows to keep those logs !

  `window.console = {
            debug : window.console.log, ...};`

Not sure about the assert support in various IE versions, but any suggestions are welcome. Also posted this answer here: [How can I use console logging in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656730/internet-explorer-console/)

Answer (score 1):

```
console = console || { 
    debug: function(){}, 
    log: function(){}
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to give an extra degree of insurance that you've got all bases covered.  Using `typeof` first will avoid any `undefined` errors.  Using `===` will also ensure that the name of the type is actually the string "undefined".  Finally, you'll want to add a parameter to the function signature (I chose `logMsg` arbitrarily) to ensure consistency, since you do pass whatever you want printed to the console to the log function.  This also keep you intellisense accurate and avoids any warnings/errors in your JS aware IDE.

```
if(!window.console || typeof console === "undefined") {
  var console = { log: function (logMsg) { } };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes console will work in IE8/9 but fail at other times. This erratic behaviour depends on whether you have developer tools open and is described in stackoverflow question [Does IE9 support console.log, and is it a real function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5473193/2732969)

Answer (score 0):

Encountered similar problem running console.log in child windows in IE9, created by window.open function.

It seems that in this case console is defined only in parent window and is undefined in child windows until you refresh them. Same applies to children of child windows.

I deal with this issue by wrapping log in next function (below is fragment of module)

```
getConsole: function()
    {
        if (typeof console !== 'undefined') return console;

        var searchDepthMax = 5,
            searchDepth = 0,
            context = window.opener;

        while (!!context && searchDepth < searchDepthMax)
        {
            if (typeof context.console !== 'undefined') return context.console;

            context = context.opener;
            searchDepth++;
        }

        return null;
    },
    log: function(message){
        var _console = this.getConsole();
        if (!!_console) _console.log(message);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

After having oh so many problems with this thing (it's hard to debug the error since if you open the developer console the error no longer happens!) I decided to make an overkill code to never have to bother with this ever again:

```
if (typeof window.console === "undefined")
    window.console = {};

if (typeof window.console.debug === "undefined")
    window.console.debug= function() {};

if (typeof window.console.log === "undefined")
    window.console.log= function() {};

if (typeof window.console.error === "undefined")
    window.console.error= function() {alert("error");};

if (typeof window.console.time === "undefined")
    window.console.time= function() {};

if (typeof window.console.trace === "undefined")
    window.console.trace= function() {};

if (typeof window.console.info === "undefined")
    window.console.info= function() {};

if (typeof window.console.timeEnd === "undefined")
    window.console.timeEnd= function() {};

if (typeof window.console.group === "undefined")
    window.console.group= function() {};

if (typeof window.console.groupEnd === "undefined")
    window.console.groupEnd= function() {};

if (typeof window.console.groupCollapsed === "undefined")
    window.console.groupCollapsed= function() {};

if (typeof window.console.dir === "undefined")
    window.console.dir= function() {};

if (typeof window.console.warn === "undefined")
    window.console.warn= function() {};
```

Personaly I only ever use console.log and console.error, but this code handles all the other functions as shown in the Mozzila Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.
Just put that code on the top of your page and you are done forever with this.

Answer (score -11):

You can use console.log(...) directly in Firefox but not in IEs. In IEs you have to use window.console.

Comment: console.log and window.console.log refer to the same function in any browser which is even remotely conformant with ECMAscript. It is good practice to use the latter to avoid a local variable accidentally shadowing the global console object, but that has absolutely nothing to do with the choice of browser. console.log works fine in IE8, and AFAIK there is no logging capability at all in IE6/7.