# Why when I enable firebug that the onclick function works in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have a web app that you can choose to click items out of the side bar, and it retrieves the contents and displays a popup when you click them in chrome, and it also works in firefox with firebug enabled, but not when its disable. it just uses onclick in the div tag. Not only that but it seemingly doesn't work for only one kind of the items. The rest work fine.

Comment: You should post some code, but it sounds to me like a <div> or something is not being closed. Firebug adds some elements to the bottom of the page, IIRC, and maybe that helps the DOM cleanup in FF figure out the missing tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is probably calling `console.log`.
In Firefox, the `console` object will only exist when Firebug is open.

To fix this, you can write

```
if (!window.console) 
    console = { log: function() { } };
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this similar question.  ['console' is undefined error for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer).  I discovered today that IE will not recognize if(!console) by itself since console is considered part of the window object.

I had to use:

```
 if (!window.console) 
    console = { log: function() { } };
```