# Does IE9 support console.log, and is it a real function?

Tags: javascript, logging, internet-explorer-9

In which circumstances is `window.console.log` defined in Internet Explorer 9?

Even when `window.console.log` is defined, `window.console.log.apply` and `window.console.log.call` are undefined. Why is this?

[Related question for IE8: [What happened to console.log in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8).]

Comment: Check out this great post about the intricacies of IE8-9 console object/function: http://whattheheadsaid.com/2011/04/internet-explorer-9s-problematic-console-object

Comment: See also ['console' is undefined error for internet explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3326650/1048572)

Comment: @MarcCliment the link is dead

Comment: @chakeda I hate when this happens, there's the link from the web archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20140625085155/http://whattheheadsaid.com/2011/04/internet-explorer-9s-problematic-console-object

Answer (score 302, accepted):

In Internet Explorer 9 (and 8), the `console` object is only exposed when the developer tools are opened for a particular tab.  If you hide the developer tools window for that tab, the `console` object remains exposed for each page you navigate to.  If you open a new tab, you must also open the developer tools for that tab in order for the `console` object to be exposed.

The `console` object is not part of any standard and is an extension to the Document Object Model.  Like other DOM objects, it is considered a host object and is not required to inherit from `Object`, nor its methods from `Function`, like native ECMAScript functions and objects do.  This is the reason `apply` and `call` are undefined on those methods.  In IE 9, most DOM objects were improved to inherit from native ECMAScript types.  As the developer tools are considered an extension to IE (albeit, a built-in extension), they clearly didn't receive the same improvements as the rest of the DOM.

For what it's worth, you can still use some `Function.prototype` methods on `console` methods with a little [`bind()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff841995%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) magic:

```
var log = Function.prototype.bind.call(console.log, console);
log.apply(console, ["this", "is", "a", "test"]);
//-> "thisisatest"
```

Comment: The same is true for Firebug's `console` object.

Comment: I can un-proudly say that for the many years I developed for the web I assumed console.log is supported by all major browsers. I just spent a day working out why IE9 doesn't like my script and now I know why - it had a console.log in the very first step. Impossible to debug, since turning debug mode made this bug go away in an instant :P Thanks for clarification!!

Comment: Had the same problem yesterday. Installing [DebugBar](http://www.debugbar.com/) happened to help me quicklier since it does not define the console object. So when I hid the IE console but not the DebugBar I got a message from latter that there was a JavaScript error (console is not defined).

Comment: you should have checked error log at the very first time the problem came to you on IE  @f055

Comment: Internet Options -> Advanced -> Display a notification about every script error. Web developers should always leave this checked in IE. This would've informed you about console, or the log function being undefined... can't remember the message exactly.

Answer (score 168):

A simple solution to this console.log problem is to define the following at the beginning of your JS code:

```
if (!window.console) window.console = {};
if (!window.console.log) window.console.log = function () { };
```

This works for me in all browsers. This creates a dummy function for console.log when the debugger is not active. When the debugger is active, the method console.log is defined and executes normally.

Comment: More info, and more robust console replacements (including other console methods) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002116/should-i-be-removing-console-log-from-production-code/15771110

Comment: @ZachL: Which ones in concrete precisely?

Comment: My answer has one approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15771110/363701. Also check this out: https://github.com/paulmillr/console-polyfill/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 14):

I know this is a very old question but feel this adds a valuable alternative of how to deal with the console issue. Place the following code before any call to console.* (so your very first script).

```
// Avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console.
(function() {
    var method;
    var noop = function () {};
    var methods = [
        'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
        'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
        'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
        'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
    ];
    var length = methods.length;
    var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

    while (length--) {
        method = methods[length];

        // Only stub undefined methods.
        if (!console[method]) {
            console[method] = noop;
        }
    }
}());
```

**Reference:**
https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v5.0.0/dist/js/plugins.js

Answer (score 10):

console.log is only defined when the console is open. If you want to check for it in your code make sure you check for for it within the window property

```
if (window.console)
    console.log(msg)
```

this throws an exception in IE9 and will not work correctly. Do not do this

```
if (console) 
    console.log(msg)
```

Answer (score 6):

After reading the article from Marc Cliament's comment above, I've now changed my all-purpose cross-browser console.log function to look like this:

```
function log()
{
    "use strict";

    if (typeof(console) !== "undefined" && console.log !== undefined)
    {
        try
        {
            console.log.apply(console, arguments);
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            var log = Function.prototype.bind.call(console.log, console);
            log.apply(console, arguments);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just `Function.prototype.apply.call(console.log, console, arguments);`

Comment: @Victor it definitely should be the only one accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention that IE9 does not raise the error if you use console.log with developer tools closed on all versions of Windows. On XP it does, but on Windows 7 it doesn't.
So if you dropped support for WinXP in general, you're fine using console.log directly.

Answer (score -1):

How about...

```
console = { log : function(text) { alert(text); } }
```

Comment: This might be a passable workaround in some cases, but you haven't actually addressed the question.