# Jquery IE Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have some Jquery written that works fine in firefox and chrome but throws an ERROR in IE.

Here is the sections of code that when taken out allow the other parts of the script to be run correctly...(otherwise the entire file is not read by IE)

```
var product_qty_is_zero = ExternalCustom_product_qty_is_zero; //'import' external variable from view.phtml
var option_is_selected = false;
var options_exist = false;
if(  ($(".options-container-big").length > 0) || ($(".options-container-small").length > 0)  )
    options_exist = true;   

$('#main-button-btn-cart').mouseenter(function() {
        //@ controlling backorder message
        if(product_qty_is_zero)
        {
            $('#select-product-reminder').slideDown(300);
            $('#select-product-reminder').text("product is purchaseable but on backorder");
            $('#select-product-reminder').css("background-color", "#c3c3c3");
        }                                          
});

$('#main-button-btn-cart').click(function() {
    if(!option_is_selected && options_exist) 
        $('#select-product-reminder').slideDown(300);
    else
        productAddToCartForm.submit();
});



 $('#select-product-reminder').slideUp(300);
  option_is_selected = true;

 var image_info = ExternalCustom_image_info; //'import' variable from media.phtml
  var image_link;
  var $selected_value_variation = $('.selected').html();
  for (var i = 0; i < image_info.length; i++) 
  {
        if(image_info[i][0] == $selected_value_variation)
            image_link = image_info[i][1];
  }
  $('#main-image').attr("href", image_link);
```

If anyone could look over it and see if there are any errors that are common for IE to flag and give me some hints it would be greatly appreciated!

Note* I already tried the class and div extensions such as 
     $('div.options-container-big') 
and 
     $('div#main-button-btn-cart')

Comment: What is the error that IE is throwing, and what are you doing to cause it?

Comment: Have you fired up a Javascript debugger to see where any exception might be getting thrown?

Comment: Your browser preferences and judgements in the question are unnecessary.

Comment: IE says the error is here...
<script type="text/javascript">if (console) { window.terminal = console; }<  But that is nowhere near where my other code is and that doesn't throw the error when my remove my lines of code

Comment: @thepristinedesign: ***What*** error? And am I missing it, or is `if (console)` nowhere in the code you've quoted? *Edit*: Nope, just copied the entire question to a text editor and searched, "console" doesn't appear anywhere within it.

Comment: 'console' is undefined. and yes, its nowhere near the code I placed that is why I am so confused.  That error does not flag if I remove my lines of code.  Reminder that this is only in IE so I figured it isn't an error in my code but rather an IE difference in reading the code

Comment: IE doesn't have a native console. IE9 does but you have to turn it on I believe. IE Tester might as well, but it doesn't always work for me.

Comment: @Alien: IE8 and IE9 both have it, but only when the developer tools are open. When they aren't, it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can see without more info that might cause some hiccups:

```
productAddToCartForm.submit();
```

If IE doesn't know what that is, it'll likely fail. Try wrapping it in JQuery-safe selector syntax:

```
$(productAddToCartForm).submit();
```

or:

```
// Assuming you have a <form id="productAddToCardForm"...>
$('#productAddToCartForm').submit();
```

Comment: The productAddToCartForm is a function call I believe to another external JS file.  Hold on let me look for it

Comment: You don't call functions that way. submit() is a function you append to a form object.

Comment: Good point.  I would like to further apologize for my web inexperience.  I had thought I saw a function that was similarily named in collection of files in the magento structure here.

Comment: I found that I pulled productAddToCartForm.submit() from the onclick value of the submit button.  I'm not sure where it gets the productAddToCartForm but this is probably the culprit here...I wonder how chrome and firefox can find it

Comment: Hey everyone.  I dont have enough reputation to post again but I resolved the issue, information continued at...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631431/javascript-jquery-commenting-causing-errors-in-ie

Answer (score 0):

You've said that IE says that `console` is undefined on the line

```
if (console) { ... // Error if `console` is not defined anywhere
```

That's quite correct. `console` is not a guaranteed built-in object on browsers, although many browsers do provide it. You probably want

```
if (typeof console !== "undefined") { ...
```

...instead. There we're not taking the *value*, we're just checking whether it exists.

This is an area of JavaScript that can get a bit confusing, but basically, if you try to take the value of an unqualified reference that really isn't declared *anywhere*, e.g.

```
if (foo) { ...
```

...it's an error. The reason this can get confusing is that you could *assign* to `foo` in the exact same situation, and it would be valid (it would be [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), but valid). Similarly, you can happily take the value of an object property that has never been defined:

```
var obj = {};
if (obj.foo) { ... // Not an error, we just don't go into the body of the `if`
```

...because that's not an unqualified reference. But with unqualified references, it's an error.

So why is `console` unqualified on IE8 and IE9, both of which have `console.log` and such? Because IE8 and IE9 don't have `console` [or `console.log`] *unless you have the developer tools open*. Strange but true. Wrong, but true. :-) Opening the developer tools, which are basically a plug-in for IE8 and IE9, adds the `console` object on-the-fly. (More on that in [this other question (and answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function) here on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply this is helpful information.  The only problem is that the code if(console) that throws the error is in the body of the page and the code I'm editing is in an external .js file.  The error does not occur when I remove my lines of code but it somehow does occur when my lines of code (posted above) are included in the external .js file

Comment: That probably means that something far away from your code that is called by your code is trying to output to the debug console.  You should probably find that suspect code and fix it.  Or you could patch the environment by adding this line of code before your code executes: `if (!window.console) {window.console = null;}`  That will make it so "if (console)" doesn't generate an error.

Comment: Sorry, the return key caused a premature posting (still fooled by no line breaks in comments).  I've finished my previous comment now.

Comment: Thanks all for the helpful comments!