# What does IE use //@ in javascript for?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex

So, a bug in a piece of javascript revolved around code similar to :

```
<script>
    (function() {
        if (true) {
            //@todo: do we need to set total or -- ?
            alert('hello?');
        }
    })();
</script>
```

In the larger system IE complained "Expected ';' ".  In the small scale example IE simply caused a warning about blocking ActiveX controls.

Obviously, "//@" has some context to activeX controls in IE.  I was unable to find this as searching for the symbols was useless, and any search about special comments in IE result in the conditional html comments.  I am just curious how the //@ are supposed to be used in IE.

Comment: Should just be a comment indicator with an @ after it

Tested in IE9, doesn't give me any errors
http://jsfiddle.net/gZsQt/1/

Comment: @celadonz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631431/javascript-jquery-commenting-causing-errors-in-ie - did you try adding a space between `//` and the `@` symbol?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't communicate well.  I solved the problem (by putting a space between the // and @ as Andreas suggested).  I was just curious what that special comment was used for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IE JScript engine supports [conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Conditional_comments_in_JScript) which turn comments written in a particular way into code (partially). However, you are not using those.

In your case it seems to be a way to tell e.g. an IDE that there is a TODO item. The error you got is most likely unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's some quirk about IE that I don't know, the `//@todo` is just commenting fluff that some programmers use when they are too lazy/don't know how to implement something.