# jQuery script only working under ie8/9 developer tools

Tags: jquery, ie-developer-tools

I am trying to debug my jQuery(Tools) script that is not working on IE. An example can be found here:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16799097/www/demo/jQuery_Slider/index.html

It loads correctly, the first (sliding) event occurs, and then nothing append.

When I try to debug my script by reloading the page with the developer-tools (press the F12 key), everything works like a charm ... What can I do if I cannot debug ?

Any help would be appreciated, I am stuck ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error is (in `slider.js`):

```
'console' is undefined
```

The `console` object [is only defined in IE when you open the Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function/5473193#5473193). Then, there's no longer a JavaScript error and everything works.

To fix the problem, you can either remove/comment out the `console.log` call, or add something like this as your very first block of JavaScript:

```
// make it safe to use console.log always
(function(b){function c(){}for(var d="assert,count,debug,dir,dirxml,error,exception,group,groupCollapsed,groupEnd,info, log,markTimeline,profile,profileEnd,time,timeEnd,trace,warn".split(","),a;a=d.pop();)b[a]=b[a]||c})(window.console=window.console||{});
```

(snippet taken from http://html5boilerplate.com/)

Comment: Unbelievable that this breaks an IE angular app.  This answer FTW