# Console.log IE9 issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, console, local-storage

I made a simple Task Manager using local.storage and I'm using console.log to set some variables but with that, the entire task app doesn't work in IE.

Is there any alternative method of doing this?

Here is the fiddle of the working Task Manager in every other browser: http://jsfiddle.net/cRse9c/

Comment: @Mystere Man. Sorry about that. Updated the link

Comment: It seems to work for me. I get `LOG: i=1 j=0 k=0` in IE9

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you want to use `console.log()` and have it not bomb out in IE when the IE debugger is not running, you can place the following in your javascript at the global scope before any `console.log()` statements execute to give you a dummy `console.log()` that will keep your `console.log()` statements from causing errors:

```
if (!window.console) {window.console = {};}
if (!console.log) {console.log = function() {};}
```

Of course, if you actually want to see the `console.log()` output in IE, then you will have to run the IE debugger which will cause `console.log()` to get defined or use some other debugging environment that defines it.

Comment: This question has some other useful info on using `console.log` in production: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002116/should-i-be-removing-console-log-from-production-code/15771110

Comment: @user3388971 - I had to rollback your edit.  `var` does not scope to the block level in Javascript and your edit removing `var` so it was an implicit declaration would have not worked in `strict` mode.  I changed it to refer to the `window` object.

Answer (score 3):

There's no console.log in IE unless you have Firebug light on. It's gonna turn into a undefined method/variable error

More information here: [Does IE9 support console.log, and is it a real function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function/5473193#5473193)

Comment: Is there any alternative method of doing it?

Comment: I usually do alerts instead of console.log, but if you want objects, you can try firebug light or follow that link. i think yo ucan turn on developer tools