# In IE11, How to use console.log?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Try to use `console.log()` But it's always printting `undefined`.

Try to use the solutions like [Console.log IE9 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424968/console-log-ie9-issue)
it does not work as well.

In this [IE11 document](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-new-ie11-f12-tools--net-34039), there is the following sentence:

`Last but not least, forget about console.log(). The new tools now support Tracepoints easily allowing you to monitor specific values the same way you would via console.log().`

What does that mean? How to use console.log to print variable in IE11?

---

System: windows 7([VirtualBox IE images](https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/5274656))

IE version:11

---

It seems `console.dir()` is an option, but how about `console.log()`? It is in the [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but why does not take effect?

Comment: You're probably looking at the return value. The console will output the return value of the last statement it executes.

Comment: But whatever the variable contains, the `console.log()` will print `undefined`, while `console.dir()` will not, why?

Comment: I have seen this before, but could not repo the issue. console.log console.info, etc all work for me normally. Do you possibly have a 3rd party library that might be changing the console object?

Answer (score 10):

Even though it's an old question, yet still giving me headache recently when working with IE11.

Simple reason: `console` object is not initiated unless devtools (i.e. pressing `F12` in IE11) is opened.

So a workaround could be, open devtools before loading `console.log()`.

In my case, `console.log` is loaded when my page is ready, so I open devtools and refresh the page to view my log.

Answer (score 4):

I recently ran into issues with console.log while running the most recent preview build of Windows 10.  Below is the code I was trying to log. The log would say my objects functions, proto, and users were ***undefined***.  I could "work around" this by changing my version of IE to 9 or putting a breakpoint on console.log(). As far as I can tell, they have just made the console methods more strict to conform with [this documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772183(v=vs.85).aspx)

The rules I follow now is to always use console.dir() when outputting objects/variables.

```
  var PM = PM || {
    users:[]
  };

  var User = (function($){
    //Private Static Variables

    //Constructor
    function User(obj){
      this.id = obj.id;
      this.first = obj.first;
      this.last = obj.last;
    };

    return User;
  })(jQuery); 

  var John = new User({
    id: 1,
    first: 'John',
    last: 'Hargis'
  });
  var Nicole = new User({
    id: 2,
    first: 'Nicole',
    last: 'Hargis'
  });

  PM.users = {
    1: John,
    2: Nicole
  };
  window.console.log(PM); //Undefined
  window.console.dir(PM); //Works
```