# Impossible retrieve resource in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sapui5

I create my OpenUI5 app and I test it in chrome (and firefox). On these browsers the app works fine but if I try to run it on Internet Explorer (In my pc I have IE11) I have a bug...

I define my resource in this mode:

```
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
        controllerName="apps.appIntra.detail.rowDetailEdit" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Page id='pageRowDetailEdit' title="Modifica" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="doBack">
        <content>
        <l:Grid
            defaultSpan="L12 M12 S12"
            hSpacing="2"
            width="auto">
            <l:content>
              <f:Form id="FormEdit"
                minWidth="1024"
                maxContainerCols="2"
                editable="true"
                class="isReadonly">
                <f:title>
                  <core:Title text="Modifica" />
                </f:title>
                <f:layout>
                  <f:ResponsiveGridLayout
                    labelSpanL="3"
                    labelSpanM="3"
                    emptySpanL="4"
                    emptySpanM="4"
                    columnsL="1"
                    columnsM="1" />
                </f:layout>
                 <f:formContainers>
                   <f:FormContainer id="rowDetFormEditContainer">

                  </f:FormContainer> 
                </f:formContainers> 
              </f:Form>
            </l:content>
          </l:Grid>

        </content>

        <footer>
          <Bar>
            <contentRight>
              <Button text="Accetta" press="onPressOnAccept" type="Accept" />
            </contentRight>
          </Bar>
        </footer>



    </Page>
</core:View>
```

Internet explorer don't like it and when I do `sap.ui.getCore().byId('rowDetailEdit').....`
it returns underined..
On FF and Chome works fine

---

I load all my view in a single step by a for cicle that instantiate the XML-views. I retrieve the name and the path of view by a my json file.

```
for( var i = 0; i < aDetailPages.length; i++) {
        var detailPage = aDetailPages[i];
        var name=detailPage.name; // "rowDetailEdit"
        var path=detailPage.path; // "apps.appIntra.detail.rowDetailEdit"
        if(sap.ui.getCore().byId(name)==undefined){
            splitApp.addDetailPage(sap.ui.xmlview(name, path)); //instantiate and add to splitapp
        } 
        else{
            sap.ui.getCore().byId(name).destroy(); //destroy old view
            splitApp.addDetailPage(sap.ui.xmlview(name, path)); //instantiate and add to splitapp
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't have a bug. IE does.

Comment: How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: I checked on my IE11 browser, and `sap.ui.getCore().byId("someViewId")` works just fine, i.e. returns a reference to the view... maybe something else with your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In IE11, How to use console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315167/in-ie11-how-to-use-console-log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the cause of the problem!
In the controller of my view I use this code:

```
console.log('Errore. Tabella della società '+sap.ui.getCore().getModel("flagSociety")+' non gestita');
```

I write `società`, whit `à` accented. 
IE don't like this char...

Comment: Unfortunately IE doesn´t like `console` at all. You should avoid using console in productive code and when testing in IE. An alternative could be to use you own `.log` method which checks if window.console exists before using it.