# jQuery dropdown not displaying first option

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-9

So, I have a dropdown filter on a client web page, the dropdown should work by matching up the class in the hidden div and displaying the relevant content. However, in IE9 (and on the linked fiddle) you can see this doesn't work.

The second option (iphone) doesn't appear to display any results. I think the issue is down to the numbering of the 'select.dropdown' function but I can't figure out what that is, exactly.

**Snippet:**

```
$("select.dropdown").change(function(){
var filters = $.map($("select.dropdown").toArray(), function(e){
    return $(e).val();
});

var filter;
if(filters[0]=="all")
{
    if(filters[1]=="all")
       filter = "";
    else
       filter = "." + filters[1];
}
else{
    if(filters[1]=="all")
       filter = "." + filters[0];
    else
       filter = "." + filters.join(".");
}
$("div#FilterContainer > div").hide();
$("div#FilterContainer").find("div" + filter).show();
console.log(filters);
```

Any ideas?

The filtering works on IE10+ and Chrome & Firefox..

Thanks in advance!

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/achello/po3hrxpn/2/)

Comment: in your `option` change `iphone` to `iPhone` ... [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/po3hrxpn/3/)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the demo too! Can't believe I missed this, back-end developer update the code and failed to mention this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your html the filter value is not correct.

```
<option value="iphone">iPhone</option>
```

value should have a capital 'P'

Comment: Yep, that's fixed it - other developer updated the code without telling me, reverting it back to a lowercase 'p'. Thanks for your help and astute eyes!

Answer (score 0):

On a hunch here, but try removing the console.log entry.

IE9 has issues with console.log entries or any other method you pass into the console object within IE9 for that matter.

#### Edit

For a better explanation - check out this question. [Console.log IE9 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424968/console-log-ie9-issue)

Comment: Thanks for the info about the console.log issue, I wasn't aware of this before, I'll keep it it mind

Answer (score 0):

Your first dropdown value has the option "iphone" (lowercase) the divs containing the results have the class name "iPhone". The cases don't match so the .find doesn't work in the following line:

```
$("div#FilterContainer").find("div" + filter).show();
```

Using the debugger in your snippet the value you search for is "div.iphone.Case" where you need "div.iPhone.Case"