# How to deal with `console.log.bind(console)` throwing error in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Using PhantomJS 1.9.x, I wanted to use `console.log.bind(console)` in my code, but it throws an error due to `console.log.bind` being `undefined` (same for `console.error.bind(console)` etc.)

**It is a known issue with PhantomJS 1.x that it does not support `Function.prototype.bind`.**

*However even after including a [`bind` polyfill](https://github.com/conversocial/phantomjs-polyfill) things are not working as expected:*

```
 console.log(Function.prototype.bind);
 // function bind(obj) { ... }
 console.log(console.log.bind);
 // undefined
```

How can I fix that issue?

Comment: Related: [How to safely wrap `console.log`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8785624/1048572) and [console.log.apply not working in IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5538972/1048572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that in PhantomJS, `console` is a bit special in that it is not an instance of `Function` (contrary to Chrome or Firefox). Hence extending `Function.prototype` has no action on it.

```
console.log(typeof console.log === "function");
// true
console.log(console.log instanceof Function);
// false
```

(probably the `console.log` comes from a different JavaScript context, and the issue here is the same as with `myArray instanceof Array` evaluating to `false` when `myArray` comes from an iframe).

To fix the issue, apart from including a polyfill for `Function.prototype.bind`, you could assign `bind` to `console` methods manually, like this:

```
if (!console.log.bind) {
    // PhantomJS quirk
    console.log.constructor.prototype.bind = Function.prototype.bind;
}
```

After this, all console methods will have `.bind()`:

```
console.log(console.log.bind);   // function bind(obj) { ... }
console.log(console.info.bind);  // function bind(obj) { ... }
console.log(console.debug.bind); // function bind(obj) { ... }
console.log(console.warn.bind);  // function bind(obj) { ... }
console.log(console.error.bind); // function bind(obj) { ... }
```

Comment: What's `Object.getPrototypeOf(console.log)` then? Maybe `console.log.__proto__ = Function.prototype` is more appropriate than what you are doing.

Comment: `console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(console.log).toString());` prints `'function () { [native code] }'`. Yes changing `__proto__` is another option, though then I'd have to change it per each `console` function, and I don't know if it won't have unexpected side issues.