# Jquery based webapp hanging ONLY with IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I'm stuck on this issue since days...

[This](http://epos-couch.cloudant.com/epos-couch/_design/epos-couch/index.html) is the site I'm talking about. It is a webapp which makes large use of backbone, visualsearch, jquery plugins. This website is not working at the moment with IE8, but it's fine that it works with IE9...if just it would!

What happens is that the website hangs when loaded ONLY with IE9 and (this is bizarre!) if the profiler tool of IE9 developer tools is ON it doesn't!!

It also happens to oher people (I was notified of that) so I'm pretty sure it's not an issue linked to my browser settings.

It makes me think about an error which has something to do with delays, or iterative functions which, in presence of profiler, are forced to delay bte cycles and so to leave free time slots to other functions which render the page.

I can update with more details if needed. thanks.

**UPDATE 01**

For the sake of simplicity I report the list of plugin I use

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script/test/vendor/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.couch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.couchLogin.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/underscore.1.3.3-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/backbone.0.9.2.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="script/visualsearch/build/visualsearch.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="script/AjaxStack/src/jsonreport/jsonreport.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/highcharts/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.simpletip-1.3.1.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/mcdropdown/lib/jquery.mcdropdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/mcdropdown/lib/jquery.bgiframe.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/gMapProgressBar/progressbar.js"></script>
    <script src="script/backbone-render/src/backbone-forms.js"></script>
    <script src="script/backbone-render/src/jquery-ui-editors.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/atooltip/js/jquery.atooltip.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBw0v9F-ur6pmeWrwCyFQ17qdZoikBon1Y&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/textualizer/textualizer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-download/jquery-download.js"></script>
```

Comment: what versions of jquery, etc are you using? Are they the latest versions?

Comment: No they aren't, but I already tried with the latest versions and it doesn't change much. What would really help me is if you can verify 1. if you have errors, 2. if you profile the page you tell me what seems to be slow or what hangs 3. Do you have the same problem with IE9 or not?

Comment: What is also weird is that if you stop the page when it hangs, then you just reload it again, then it works perfectly. It makes me think that there are some issues with logging in or caching...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long debugging I found the solution:

the problem  **NOT REPORTED AS AN ERROR BY IE9** was that the `console.log()` commands makes IE9 stuck when developer tools are closed.

More info in this issue can be found at this post: [Does IE9 support console.log, and is it a real function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function)

Answer (score 0):

What helped for me is to remove (comment out) functions until I found the culprit, but then again I did have an error of being out of stackspace for that problem