# How to see the xml object in IE 9 console / or VS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

```
var log = Function.prototype.bind.call(console.log, console);  

jQuery.get("metadata.xml", function(metadata){  
            xmlCols = $(metadata).find('UXView');//'.find('ListDefintion').find('uxv\\:Column');
        log.apply(console, [xmlCols]);
});
```

console.log works perfectly fine in chrome but this work around (to get console.log equivalent in IE 9 as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function) in stackoverflow itself), in IE displays [object object] in console.  When I try to see it in a watch it shows the whole object with all the properties of it and I have no idea how to see the actual xml in there?

If there is a way to see it in visual studio (using debugger command) either, I can use it but till now it shows the same thing over there too.
Thanks...