# Getting logs in Internet Explorer 8 and 9 without opening developer tool view

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, logging, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

Chrome, FireFox and Safari can all log to the console without having the developer tool view open. However, IE 8 and 9 (not sure about 10) cannot, as `console` will be undefined without opening the developer tool first.

Is there any workaround for this? External JavaScript library?

Comment: I think ExtJS has a cross-browser debugger with an internal console.

Comment: are you sure? I just tried ie 9 and console.log is defined without me opening dev tools.

Comment: @rambocoder, really? I am not getting this in `IE9 Ver: 9.0.8112.16421`

Comment: I'm using the same version. http://jsfiddle.net/VsT3U/ gives me "native code"

Comment: actually nevermind. on a fresh browser opening, it doesn't work.

Comment: @rambocoder, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function, did you open the developer tool view first and then hide it?

Comment: yes, that post explains why it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.console = window.console || {log: function(){}};
```

THis wont let you access the logs, but it will avoid null pointer errors.

Comment: interesting, saves a check for each `console.log`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of any library that will help you with this in IE but you could encapsulate your logging within a method so that it will operate normally in IE when not in developer mode.

```
function log(val){
  if(console.log){
    console.log(val);
  }
}
```

Comment: Store the `val` in the DOM or inside a global for later retrieval perhaps, as a fallback for missing `console.log`, with `console = { 'log': function(val) { fallbacklog.push(val); } }`

Comment: @kmb385, or this: `window.console && console("log something here");`