# How to print to the screen - "console.log is not a function"

Tags: javascript

I have tried numerous ways...what am I doing wrong??? I am determined to learn and really understand this.

```
//On line 2, declare a variable myName and give it your name.
var myName = "Jeanne";
//On line 4, use console.log to print out the myName variable.
console.log ("Jeanne");
//On line 7, change the value of myName to be just the first 2 letters of your name.
myName.substring(0, 2);
//On line 9, use console.log to print out the myName variable;
console.log("Jeanne");
```

Comment: the error that I keep getting is: TypeError: console.log is not a function, which is partly why I am confused.

Comment: If using IE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function/5473193#5473193 (Search as appropriate if you are using a different browser/environment.)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are using a browser that supports `console.log`(Firefox with Firebug, Google Chrome) if you are having problems with your browser, try to run your code in jsfiddle

**EDIT**

I have tried to run your code in jsfiddle, and in my browser(Chrome and IE9), they both work perfectly.

Based from the comment that I have read you're using firefox. if that's the case make sure you have the firebug plugin installed. you can get it [here](http://getfirebug.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `assign` to the result of substring back to variable to get the substring result. Use that varible to print the `substring result`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/uN2jh/1/)**

```
myName = myName.substring(0, 2);
console.log(myName );
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably your error is that you getting "Jeanne" on screen every time.

It is because you are printing constant, and not your variable. Try use this for printing:

```
myName = myName.substring(0, 2);
console.log (myName);
```

And as stated in the other answers - make sure you are using a browser that supports console.log

Comment: @tooheymomster Well, that would be so easily addressed *if including such information in the post*. I suspect it is because an older version of IE is being used ..

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it all correct just log the processed variable instead of raw name,Done !

```
//On line 2, declare a variable myName and give it your name.
var myName = "Jeanne";
//On line 4, use console.log to print out the myName variable.
console.log (myName );
//On line 7, change the value of myName to be just the first 2 letters of your name.
myName=myName.substring(0, 2);
//On line 9, use console.log to print out the myName variable;
console.log(myName );
```

Answer (score 1):

Among other things, make sure you're using a browser that supports "console.log". This means Chrome, or FireFox with the Firebug plugin installed, or Internet Explorer *with the developer tools open*. And then of course open the developer tools. For Chrome, it's ctrl-shift-I; for everything else it's F12.

Comment: In which case, make sure you install Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Inorder for the console.log to print out your var value, you should include the **variable** in between paraenthesis of the *console.log*

this is shown in the below example;

//On line 2, declare a variable myName and give it your name.
var myName = "Jeanne";

//On line 4, use console.log to print out the myName variable.
console.log (myName);

Comment: That wasn't the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in immutable so you should assign the results to a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help! I really appreciate you being available and knowledgeable to answer questions. I did figure it out. Apparently the problem was with the substring. I had typed out the word substring in full. I guess it didn't like that and only needed the abbreviated substr.

```
//On line 2, declare a variable myName and give it your name.
var myName = "Jeanne";
//On line 4, use console.log to print out the myName variable.
console.log (myName);
//On line 7, change the value of myName to be just the first 2 
//letters of your name.
myName = myName.substr(0,2);
//On line 9, use console.log to print out the myName variable;
console.log (myName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the `console.log is not a function` error, and spent a frustrating 15 minutes debugging it. It turned out I had a local variable called `console`! using `window.console.log("...")` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you assigned something else to console.log, something that wasn't a function console.log = 5 console.log()

// obviously not referring to a function any more restart your environment. ie. refresh the page