# How to print a value in console.log base on ID of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, console.log

```
<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="ooooo@gmail.com">
```

How do I get value of id=email and print it out to my console or anywhere for testing purposes ?

I tried, but no luck :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('email').innerText;
</script>
```

Comment: You want to use `.value`, not `.innerText`.

Comment: Keep in mind that not all browsers support console, and some will throw an error if you try to use the console object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086675/which-browsers-support-console-log

Comment: I guess I should consider using .innerText

Comment: `document.getElementById('email').value`. Incidentally if you are debugging interactively with chrome $0 to $4 remembers the last five DOM elements you've selected in the developer tools so you can simply run $0.value in the console.

Comment: @Hoppe, pointless link and discussion.. console.log is for development purposes.. ontop of which, it's an easy pollyfill

Answer (score 6):

There are two types of elements

1. Block - these can be accessed with - `.innerHTML` or `.html()` in jquery like div's span's etc
2. Non Block Elements - these can be accessed by `.value` or `.val()` in jquery, like input types etc

all you need o do is

```
console.log($('#email').val())  //jquery

or 

console.log(document.getElementById('email').value); // javascript
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
console.log($('#email').val());
```

Comment: But you'll have to add it to an event, like an onclick of a button of value changed event of that input to log it in the console

Comment: Is `alert`, and `console.log` are the only 2 ways to print out the value base on ID if an element ? I'm looking for a better alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Without jQuery:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('email').value);
```

Comment: Is `alert`, and `console.log` are the only 2 ways to print out the value base on ID if an element ? I'm looking for a better alternative.

Comment: If you have another div, you can output the result to that div. Ex:
`document.getElementById('textDiv').innerHTML = document.getElementById('email').value`

Comment: @evoque2015: Better how? Why is `console.log()` insufficient for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try an alert...

http://jsfiddle.net/nemb666L/

```
var email = $("#email").val();
alert(email);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why people even do alerts anymore.. just use the console.log..

it's much easier to test code using the intermediate console, developers need to become more familiar with it.

Comment: "console.log is only suitable for live debugging and behaves differently in Firefox, Chrome and IE (in IE it will display the same text as the alert)." I guess it depends on the situation...

Answer (score 1):

this will 'print' the entire object to the console

```
console.log("input[id='email'] - %o", document.getElementById('email'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It works

```
console.log(email.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Chrome dev tools console drop the .value:

```
document.getElementById('#id')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let inputId = document.querySelector("#email");
console.log(inputId.value);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

If `email`(your id) is not defined, just:

```
email.innerHTML
```

[image]