# JQuery ajax function json data always SyntaxError

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, get

JQuery with some very simple GET Method call and transfer data using the json program
But constantly ran error, then IE tells me "SyntaxError"

But I have removed the data parameter is ok ...

Please help us to see in the end the problem? Thank you !!

```
var url = "/demo/test.do";
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  data: jQuery.parseJSON('[{"dispatch" : "add"}]'),
  success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Comment: Console.log() does not work in IE. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086675/which-browsers-support-console-log

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log -- Though you can add a super-basic shim: `if (typeof console==='undefined'){console={log:function(){}};}` -- that will make a fake console for browsers that don't support it. Speaking best-practice wise, you should not have any use of console.log in live code, or use that shim. For development, it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

IE and console.log has issues unless ie8 has Dev tools enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.   No need to try to parse the JSON for the input.

```
 var url = "/demo/test.do";
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   method: "GET",
   dataType: "json",
   data: {
       "dispatch" : "add"
   },
  success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});
```