# Is console.log ever undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, logging

If there is any case where `console.log` is undefined, I would need to define it or wrap my logging calls in my own log function.

Is there any javascript runtime environment where `console.log` could be undefined? By runtime environment I mean a browser or other environments like Node.

Comment: "Anywhere" is a lot of places. IE6?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086675/which-browsers-support-console-log

Comment: The question is very general on purpose, to include runtime environments like browsers, Node, or something else.

Answer (score 2):

In IE9-, `console.log` only exists when the developer console is openned.

If you need to logs in those browsers, it may be a good idea to deactivate console or to test before logging.

To make console.log works on those old browsers, a tricky but smart way is to set at the start of your JS this code:

```
if (!window.console) window.console = {};
if (!window.console.log) window.console.log = function() {};
```

<sup>[Credits to Michael Erickson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9593812/4927984)</sup>

---

For further details, here is a [very complete blog](http://patik.com/blog/complete-cross-browser-console-log/) about cross-browser compatibility.