# Why can't I bind directly console.log on IE9 with developer tools open?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, console, function-binding

With developer tools open in IE9, this code works :

```
var log = Function.prototype.bind(console.log, console);
```

But if I type

```
console.log(console, console.log);
var log = console.log.bind(console);
```

then I get this :

[image: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'bind']

Why ?

Is that a known IE bug or a normal behavior ?

Does it affect other functions (I had no problem with `window.alert` which is also native) ?

Comment: Check this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5473193/1915183

Comment: @MarioBellart The other answer mainly says "it's a bug". Right ? Is this bug referenced somewhere ?

Comment: sorry, not sure if it's a bug and don't know where I can check a submitted iexplorer bug list. I understand (copied from the answer) "The console object is not part of any standard and is an extension to the Document Object Model. Like other DOM objects, it is considered a host object and is not required to inherit from Object, nor its methods from Function" so I deduce, bind, as call or apply, are undefined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the related answer says, it is simply because the `log` function from the `console` object in IE doesn't inherit from `Function`. It's a host object, and it uses whatever rules IE sees fit.

But it's a function-like. That's why using `Function.prototype.bind` works, just like using `Array.prototype.forEach` works on array-like objects. (Hint: NodeLists and HTMLCollections.)

It's not a bug per se, because there is no specification talking about the `console` object. The [DOM living standard](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/) doesn't even mention it. So each browser implements this object the way it wants to.

And it does mean that the `window.alert` function is subject to the same problems. We're lucky that it works so well across browsers.

That's IE. Deal with it. Although IE9 is far better than IE8, it's still way worse than the other modern browsers.

Comment: The DOM standard doesn't specify it but when a feature doesn't work as expected (for example a back button which closes an application sometimes), it's a bug (at least for my customers).

Comment: @dystroy so it's a bug according to what you expect. Unfortunately, IE's referential isn't you.

Answer (score 5):

console is an extension of DOM and it is not part of ECMAScript. Since its a host object it is not required to inherit from 'Object'. In IE (9 & 8) console is only exposed when developer toolbar is opened.

```
var log = Function.prototype.bind.call(console.log, console); 
log(60+90);//150
```