# TypeError: Illegal Invocation console.log

Tags: javascript

I am learning about JavaScript abstraction. I want to pass a function as a parameter into another function. When I pass in console.log it returns a TypeError:Illegal invocation

```
function forEvery(array,action){
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
       action(array[i]);
    }
}

forEvery(["test1","test2","test3"],console.log);
```

I expect this to log all the elements in the passed array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `console.log` isn't called with the right context (`this`).

Change

```
forEvery(["test1","test2","test3"],console.log);
```

to

```
forEvery(["test1","test2","test3"], Function.prototype.bind(console.log, console));
```

Note that this would be simpler with an non native function: you would have used

```
forEvery(["test1","test2","test3"], console.log.bind(console));
```

which also works on most browsers.

But there's a "limitation" in IE9 (and probably some other versions). [See related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233258/why-cant-i-bind-directly-console-log-on-ie9-with-developer-tools-open).

Comment: Worth noting that there's no *guarantee* that host-provided functions like `console.log` are real functions, so there's no guarantee they'll have `Function#bind`. But I think in all modern browsers, it does.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In fact, you made me remember [my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233258/why-cant-i-bind-directly-console-log-on-ie9-with-developer-tools-open). IE9 isn't so old so I'll edit