# jQuery.push into array returning undefined

Tags: jquery, arrays, push, undefined

I'm trying to push data from this h5 tag to my favorites array but it keeps returning undefined. It does return something, and it works on the click, but it just keeps returning undefined.

```
<h5 id="favoriteartist"> Armin van Buuren </h5>
```

And here's my script.

```
$('#favoriteadd').live('click',function() {
    var favorites = []
    favorites.push( $('h5 #favoriteartist').val() );
    console.log(favorites);
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. Simple use:

```
$("#favoriteartist");
```

And also you should use `.text` not `.val`:

```
favorites.push( $("#favoriteartist").text() );
```

And if you are using jQuery 1.7+ you should use `.on` not `.live`:

```
$(document).on('click', '#favoriteadd', function() {
    var favorites = []
    favorites.push( $('#favoriteartist').text() );
    console.log(favorites);
});
```

Now you can change `document` with a static selector. If `#favoriteadd` is in the docuement when the event is bound you can simple bind it as a normal event:

```
$('#favoriteadd').on('click', function() {
    var favorites = []
    favorites.push( $('#favoriteartist').text() );
    console.log(favorites);
});
```

---

`h5 #favoriteartist` is like saying:

1. Give me all h5 elements on the whole page.
2. Now give me all elements with the id `favoriteartist` witch is a (grand-)child of these h5.

We know that an id in html is always unique, so we simple say:

1. Give me the element with the id `favoriteartist`.

Comment: and add the `;` in second line and not use `console.log` in IE etc.

Comment: @bart why not use console.log in IE?

Comment: @NULL we know that an id is required to be unique but that's not the same as your claim that it will always be unique. THe rendering will work but any functionality that relies on ids might not

Comment: @RuneFS in IE it might be that console.log is not defined and will break the javascript AFAIK.

Comment: Cheers for the instant response! It worked like a charm. Do you know how it's possible to make the array add up like this ["Armin van Buuren, "2nd click", "3rd click" etc etc]?

Comment: @barts You can make an fallback for development (In global scope:) `var console;console=console||{log:function(){}};`

Comment: @barts learned something new. It's supported but only if you have had the dev console open for the active tab (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5473193/112407)

Comment: @RuneFS IE7 doesn't support the console object at all. And Think IE10 always support it.

Comment: @RuneFS learning new things is good. I mentioned it because I learned it only recently myself

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not return undefined. It returns an array with one element. The element is `undefined` meaning your selector is selecting an `h5` element that does not have a value and val() of that selection therefor returns undefined. `.val()` can be used on eg. an text input field to get the value the user have typed in

```
<input type="text" id="t" value="..." />
...
$("#t").val(); //will return the value of the input element
```

in the case of a h5 element if you wish to get the textual content of that element use `.text()` instead.

```
$("#favoriteartist").text(); //will return " Armin van Buuren "
```