# JQuery document ready function not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, domdocument

I have a function I'm using to replace some text output with a button or sold out label accordingly.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('td.register').each(function () {
    var text = jQuery(this).text();
    var exploded = text.split(',');
    console.log(exploded[0]);
    console.log(exploded[1]);
    if (exploded[0] == 0) {
        jQuery(this).html("<font color='red'>SOLD OUT</font>");
    } else {
        jQuery(this).html("<a class='button' title ='Register for this event' href='" + exploded[1] + "'>Register</a>"); 
    }
})
});
```

It seems to work fine on most browsers, but the client is complaining in IE9 it's not working. When I test it on my computer, most of the time it works, but sometimes it doesn't, and *every* time I test it on browsershots.org it doesn't work. It shows up in browsershots.org tests as if the jQuery didn't even run.

Comment: It's because you use `console.log()` which is available in IE9 [only when the dev tools are open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function). Just remove those lines and it should work.

Comment: And as a side note, you might want to make sure the content looks ok and preferably works even when JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: I found this by Googling "document ready function doesn't work in internet explorer". But I wonder how I could have discovered this problem myself? How could I have tracked it down? As a side note, I had some issues on an AJAX page and then discovered the `ajaxComplete` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

console is not defined in IE9 modify your code like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('td.register').each(function () {
    var text = jQuery(this).text();
    var exploded = text.split(',');
    if(typeof(console)!='undefined'){
        console.log(exploded[0]);
        console.log(exploded[1]);
    }
    if (exploded[0] == 0) {
        jQuery(this).html("<font color='red'>SOLD OUT</font>");
    } else {
        jQuery(this).html("<a class='button' title ='Register for this event' href='" + exploded[1] + "'>Register</a>"); 
    }
})
});
```

Comment: I can't believe that was it. And the reason I couldn't reproduce it is what Juhana said above - it works when dev tools are open. Thank you!

Comment: IE does such thing to you `;)`, glad that resolved your problem

Comment: Helped me to understand IE9 doesn't have console. Couldn't figure out why my code wasn't working while all the time it was caused by console ;) Thank you, +1