# facebook connect with javascript sdk is not working in IE?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have developed a facebook connect app for my website with javascript sdk. It works fine with all browser except IE.

In IE it sometimes don't call the test API function a user clicked on the Login button. Login window popups and when user enter user name and password it should call the testAPI function. But sometime the function calling won't work. But sometimes if I refresh the browser and try again it works.

Does any one here faces this type of problem.
Below is my javascript code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//localhost/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // connected
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // not_authorized
      login();
    } else {
      // not_logged_in
      login();
    }
  });

    // Additional init code here

  };



  function login() { //alert("test");
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // connected
          testAPI();
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    }, { scope: 'email' });
    }

  function testAPI() {
    //document.write ("tet");
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {

        //document.write("sdfs");
        //document.write(response.name);
        var test = response.first_name; //alert(test);
        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.first_name + '.');
        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.last_name + '.');
        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.id + '.');
        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.email + '.');
       // console.log(response);
    });
  }

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
```

Comment: habe you tried checking the console using the IE developer tools

Comment: @FabioAntunes Yes. I have tested with ie developer tools. But It fails to call testAPI() function sometime and sometime it does.
I don't know why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the problem is the console object is not supported by IE, and the stupid thing is if you turn internet explorer developer tools, console object is supported.

So just remove all the console.log lines, they work when you have the developers tools open but they won't work if developer tools are closed. This is so stupid that makes it even harder to debug.

Instead try using alerts.

You can read a better explanation here:

[Does IE9 support console.log, and is it a real function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function)