# AngularJS Internet Explorer 9

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-9

I have small trouble with angularjs and internet explorer9. It look like, that angularjs is not loading correctly. If I starting ie with my application, nothing will work, but if I start the development tools of ie9 and refresh the page, my application will work and everything is loading and ready to use.

I have no idea, what happen and how to solve this issue. I using angularJs Version 1.1.5. Big thanks!

### Update & Resolved

My problem was, that I had everywhere console.log (..). On FF or Chrome, everything works, but with II9, something happens, that ie stop after the statement console.log(...); After removing console.log(..) from my JavaScript, my application also works on IE7/8/9.

### But ??

But I would ask why IE has so much problems with console.log?

Comment: Do you necessarily have to open the developer tools or a simple refresh also works?

Comment: Only refresh doesnt work, only if the dev Tools is Open

Comment: Had the same issue with IE8.  Baezy's answer was correct (and should be marked as such).  I took out two console.log() lines from my app and it worked.

Comment: console.log() on IE8 and IE9 is enabled only after opening dev tools for a tab: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5473193/3211434. As @Pavel mentions below, always use $log.

Answer (score 15):

I run in to the same issue and what fixed it was creating window console in the parent controller before using it. You can add the following code and try.

```
window.console = window.console || {};
window.console.log = window.console.log || function() {};
```

Comment: I cannot tell you how much time you probably just saved me with this.  Thanks!

Comment: After hours of trying to figure out what was wrong with out intranet app I found this. If only I had found you sooner. I have a debuggingmode flag set as a global variable and only expose console.log when this is true.

Answer (score 4):

Use `$log` service. It will be injected in your controllers. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$log

Comment: Just a comment, using $log.log("...") will also have same problem, using $log.info(...) can work in IE.

Answer (score 3):

Are you making a call to console.log in your code?
If yes, this will not be available in IE unless you open the dev tools.

Comment: ok my mistake. Of course that all logs will be visible in dev tools of ie. In my case, my page will not loaded correctly (angularjs stops), binding i broken, my list will not fill up ( ng-repeat) etc.
If i open the dev tools of ie and reloading the page, everythink works

Comment: Thanks for posting this question. I had the same issue. IE Idiosyncrasies I guess.