# AEM AngularJS not working on IE9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, aem

I found peculiar issue in IE9 with Adobe Experience Manager(Adobe CMS Platform), Angular JS ng-app on body attribute is removed when I load the test and target(Adobe tracking platform) js file. Can any of you suggest fix for the same. And found it works fine with IE10+, Chrome & Firefox. I have tried rename all directive from "ng-app" to "data-ng-app" but this also still not working for me.

Comment: Any help on the above please?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other issues with IE9, such as loading XMLHttp requests and also some page expiring stuff:

[link to similar stackoverflow q.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567729/angular-js-not-working-with-ie9-but-works-with-other-browsers)

There may be also some console logging:

[logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025509/angularjs-internet-explorer-9)

I've seen some other stuff and does the IE9 console tell you anything? If mbox is causing you issues then you can place an error handling around that module, or remove the inclusion of the module until you have resolved other problems.

Comment: I'm able to crack down issue is with base tag which I'm using in page level.

Comment: And another finding is that Adobe target JS(mbox.js) is giving error if you use with angular JS library which is causing script error on page load.

Comment: I've seen the mbox errors in the past and by and large they can be ignored. Have you solved the issue now?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the below code is blocking in IE9 and commenting on the below code in main controller fixed the issue now.

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

I'm not sure why it is breaking on this. Even base tag issue not happening after commenting the above script.