# javascript file dont work on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery

my site javascript functions normaly work on all browsers except internet explorer 9 , in i7 & ie8 also  work normaly.
After a long testing i  came to the conclusion that,js file  just does not work, but why ?
The interesting thing is that in some cases it works fine, but I do not know in which cases.
After updating the second time is always working properly.
site link is http://calypsoaccessories.com/

Comment: Post the relevant javascript code here. Don't just post links to your site. Do the developer tools show any errors?

Comment: "`... js file just does not work ...`" Really telling all, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove all `console.log` from your script

Comment: IE until version 10(i guess) does not support `console.log` the way we used to it here is a [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function) with  explanation