# Website breaks in IE9 but works when Developer Tools is opened

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, doctype, ie-developer-tools

This is my website, [eTraining](http://etraining.esc.rl.ac.uk). It works good on Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer 10. But on IE 9, the Tag Cloud on the front page doesn't show up, but when I open Developers Tool (F12) and refresh the page, it works. It is kind of weird bug to me.

I don't know what is causing this error. I assume it is because of Doctype declaration.

I have used this on the top of the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have any console.log() in your code? IE < 9 does not expose the console object unless the  developer tool is open. For further details see 
[Does IE9 support console.log, and is it a real function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for finding out the error. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9593812/2798227 This worked. :)