# Works in Chrome, but not in IE9...?

Tags: d3.js, internet-explorer-9

The following code works fine in Chrome, but the .on(click) event does not seem to work in IE9.   I am obviously missing something.

Link: jsfiddle.net/CDPLz

Comment: Try loading your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ and providing a link to that instead

Comment: Link:  http://jsfiddle.net/CDPLz/

Comment: @paul.abbot.wa.us Good catch.   Not sure why, but that fixes it for me as well.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you comment out `console.log(barChartData),` the bar chart works (I assume that is the problem you were having).

See [Does IE9 support console.log, and is it a real function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function).