# setInterval Breaks Page To Be Shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have that line of code:

```
var checkExist5 = setInterval(function() {
    if (lock == 5 && $("#id1").length && $("#id2").length) {            
        console.log("debug");
        clearInterval(checkExist5);           
        lock = -1;
    }
}, 100);
```

it works at Firefox but it breaks the page at Internet Explorer. It does not give any error at console but the page is not shown (ie 9). What may be the reason?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code. Is the dev tool's console open when it runs?

Comment: Are you sure that this snippet is the culprit?

Comment: Throw in alert or debugger statements to see if they are hit?

Comment: I've tried it with both it is open and not. Is it related to I should do: ` down vote accepted
 

Try disabling the cache with ajaxSetup

$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses */
    cache: false
});` ?

Comment: What does Ajax have to do with that code snipplet you provided?

Comment: Have you tried using longer interval?

Comment: @undefined What would a longer interval do?

Comment: longer interval did not change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. It was because of

console.log("debug");

It was not working at Internet Explorer 9. There is an explanation here: [Does IE9 support console.log, and is it a real function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function)