# Internet Explorer Function Inside a Function Does Not Work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have that script:

```js
var information = function() {    

  this.paco= function() {  
 console.log("function called");
  };
  
  this.paco();

}();
```

and this:

```
var information = function() {    

  var paco= function() {  
    console.log("function called");
  };

  paco();

}();
```

but this works:

```
var information = function() {    
...
  this.paco= function() {  
    console.log("function called");
  };

  //this.paco();
...
}();
```

it works at Firefox but does not work at Internet Explorer and does not log any error to console. When I try to call a function inside `information` I get this log:

```
Object doesn't support this action
```

Here is some info: http://www.spilgames.com/javascript-bug-in-internet-explorer-8-and-older/ I can not put all the code because there are many scripts calls each other. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give more context and perhaps preceed each code snippet with what works or doesn't work. I a not clear because when I run each of those code snippets in IE and FF, they are working as they should.

Comment: I've turned your sample into a snippet, then I went to IE and it worked...

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the problem in IE 8.

Comment: Why are you using `this` inside an IEFE at all? Is that property named `paco` in your actual script as well?

Comment: Neither function has a return statement, so they return *undefined*, so *information* has a value of *undefined*.

Comment: I have tried `this` and not but did not worked. I also used `var` as explained here: http://www.spilgames.com/javascript-bug-in-internet-explorer-8-and-older/ I can not put all the code because there are many scripts calls each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. It was because of

```
console.log("function called");
```

It was not working at Internet Explorer 9. There is an explanation here: [Does IE9 support console.log, and is it a real function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function)