# Testing for console.log statements in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['console' is undefined error for internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer)

If you have `console.log` statements in your code, Internet Explorer will throw a JavaScript error (at least in IE7 which is what our intranet users have installed).

I am using Firefox for most of my development testing primarily because of the functionality provided by Firebug (where I use a lot of console statements) but I also need to test in IE.

if I add the following to my JavaScript, the error does not get thrown.

```
var debugging = false;
if (typeof console == "undefined") 
    var console = { log: function() {} };
```

The problem is that I would like to trigger an event if debugging mode is false.  If I create a function to test whether debugging is false and do an action (at this point just an alert) but when I try do the following I receive an IE error saying **Console is not defined**.

```
var debugging = false; // or true   
if (typeof console == "undefined") 
    var console = { log: function() {consoleMsg()} };   

function consoleMsg() {
    if(!debugging) {
    alert('Console.log event in Production Code');
}
```

If someone could help me to fix my code, provide a better way to help me achieve my goal, or direct me to a resource to edumacate myself I would be very appreciative.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer check

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You don't have to jump through all these hoops. Simply check if the console exists before using it.

So, instead of:

```
console.log('foo');
```

Use:

```
window.console && console.log('foo');
```

...and you won't get any errors.

---

Alternatively, you could just check for it at the top of your script, and if it's undefined, just fill it with an empty function:

```
// At the top of your script:
if ( ! window.console ) console = { log: function(){} };
// If you use other console methods, add them to the object literal above

// Then, anywhere in your script:
console.log('This message will be logged, but will not cause an error in IE7');
```

---

For a more robust solution, use this piece of code (taken from twitter's source code):

```
// Avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console.
(function() {
    var method;
    var noop = function () {};
    var methods = [
        'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
        'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
        'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
        'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
    ];
    var length = methods.length;
    var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

    while (length--) {
        method = methods[length];

        // Only stub undefined methods.
        if (!console[method]) {
            console[method] = noop;
        }
    }
}());
```

Comment: That'd still give a `ReferenceError` if `console` is not defined.

Comment: @pimvdb - forgot to add the `window.` part. Thanks. Updated.

Comment: Fixed a minor bug: Must be `window.console || (console = { log: function(){} });` instead of `window.console || console = { log: function(){} };`

Comment: +1 for the piece of code taken from Twitter's source code. Good spot and share (and honesty with source).

Comment: Does *NOT* work on IE - you must call typeof(console). Did you even test this on IE6/7/8?

Comment: @ComputerLinguist - It sure does. I just tested it in IE8.

Comment: Looks like the dev toolbar for IE will define 'console' but not 'console.log'..

Comment: @ComputerLinguist - Regular users don't use the dev toolbar. If you're concerned about that, use the *more robust solution* at the bottom of my answer. That's what it's there for.

Comment: I've also gotten reports of it happening in the wild, on machines without the toolbar. Perhaps there's other javascript defining `console` but not `console.log`.

Comment: I'd add `typeof console[method].apply !== "function"` for the odd case in which the IE dev toolbar _is_ open - in which case console.log.apply fails (this can be an issue w/ angularjs).

Answer (score 6):

'console' itself needs to be a function, as well as 'log'.  So:

```
if(typeof(console) === 'undefined') {
    console = function(){};
    console.log = function(){consoleMsg()};
}
```

Comment: Why should it be a function? I tried: `console()`, and got an error: `object 'console' is not a function`

Comment: It is an object in Firefox with firebug, Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Comment: Appreciate the attempt to add additional information to this answer, but it would be more appropriate to create a new answer with the suggested expanded capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `try-catch`:

```
var debugging = false; // or true 
try {  
    console.log();
} catch(ex) {
    /*var*/ console = { log: function() {consoleMsg()} };   
}
```

Comment: +1 I put this at the top of my js and now I can use `console.log(myVariable)` anywhere, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(debug) {
    var console;

    function wrapConsoleMethod(fnName) {
        if(fnName in console)
            console[ fnName ] = function(fn) {
                return function() {
                    if(debug)
                        return fn.apply(console, arguments);
                    else
                        alert('Console event in Production Code');
                };
            }(console[ fnName ]);
        else
            ; // fn not in console
    };

    if(!('console' in window))
        window.console = {
            log : function() {}
            // ...
        };
    console = window.console;
    wrapConsoleMethod('log');
    // ...
})(true /* debug */);

console.log('test');
```