# Is there a way to log to console without breaking code under IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, logging

I'm trying to use console.log to put some logging into the javascript side of my program. I noticed, though, that unless the dev console is open in IE, JS basically stops working when it hits console.log. This is a pain... it means I have to remove all the logging whenever I want to do a production build.

Aside from the obvious:

```
function DoSafeConsoleLog( parameters )
{
    if ( !$.browser.msie )
    {
         console.log( parameters ); 
    }
}
```

is there a good way to log javascript that is friendly to all major browsers?

EDIT:

Well, after looking at the duplicate post (oops) as well as considering the answers here, I've gotta side with just checking for the existence of console before calling. Even though I am loathe to have the extra markup, I would rather not step on the feet of future programmers who might want to use Firebug Lite to debug my code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing for console.log statements in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585351/testing-for-console-log-statements-in-ie)

Comment: possible duplicate of ['console' is undefined error for internet explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IE has its own console, and you wont want to override console if you're using [firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite). Just make sure that console exists when log gets called:

```
if (window.console) console.log('foo bar baz', fizz, buzz);
```

Better yet, use `&&` to shortcut:

```
window.console && console.log('foo bar baz', fizz, buzz);
```

Comment: What do you mean "IE has its own console?" The console it provides works happily with console.log IF the developer console is open. The other browsers are able to log to their console even if it is not explicitly open. Just curious, not saying your answer is incorrect at all. You definitely have valid points I am considering. :)

Comment: I switched to `window.console && console.log()` and now everything works in IE!

Comment: Just a heads-up, it is mostly a bad idea to let `console.log`s seep into your production code.

Answer (score 15):

You can create a fake `console`:

```
if (typeof console === "undefined")
    console = { log: function() { } };
```

Comment: I'm not particularly fond of this idea as it would override consoles added after page load such as [Firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

Comment: Honestly I fought with firebug lite a lot and ended up removing it. I found that Chrome's developer console was enough for me to figure things out on -- and Firebug lite would glitch out probably once a day and have to be closed. Just my experiences, though.

Comment: @Sean Anderson, `<!--[if IE]--><script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script><!--[endif]-->` will add it only for IE.

Answer (score 1):

I use this snippet myself

```
if (! ('console' in window) ) {
var names = ['log', 'debug', 'info', 'warn', 'error', 'assert', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'group', 'groupEnd', 'time', 'timeEnd', 'count', 'trace', 'profile', 'profileEnd'];
window.console = {};
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) window.console[names[i]] = function() {};
}else {
/*if it exists but doesn't contain all the same methods....silly ie*/
var names = ['log', 'debug', 'info', 'warn', 'error', 'assert', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'group', 'groupEnd', 'time', 'timeEnd', 'count', 'trace', 'profile', 'profileEnd'];
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) if(!window.console[names[i]])window.console[names[i]] = function() {};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function log(log){
  try{
     console.log( log); 
  }catch(err){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [fauxconsole](http://icant.co.uk/sandbox/fauxconsole/); I modified the css a bit so that it looks nicer but works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the "fake console" described above, to prevent the script execution breaking. 
It is included only for InternetExplorer < 10.
I include this in my html head:

```
<!--[if lte IE 10]>
  <script> if (typeof console === "undefined") console = { log: function() { } }; </script>
<![endif]-->
```