# What do i need to get javascript working in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

this javascript  does not work on IE 8, in chrome and firefox it does.

The complete site is found [here](http://www.pand89.nl/pand_89/CI/index.php/site3/pagina1)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function get_random()
{
    var ranNum= Math.floor(Math.random()*35);
    return ranNum;
}

function pickBG(){

    var i = 1 + get_random();
    console.log(i);
    document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('/pand_89/CI/images/bgSet/" + i + ".jpg')";
}
```

DO i need a different doctype or something?

Thanks!

Comment: you could try [ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/), which help standardise IE's HTML/CSS support

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892509/is-there-a-way-to-log-to-console-without-breaking-code-under-ie

Comment: _"does not work"_ - and nothing happens, or something happens but not what you expected, or you get an error message, or...? (EDIT: OK, so it'll be the console.log() problem.)

Comment: possible duplicate of ['console' is undefined error for internet explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`console.log()` does not work in IE unless the F12 console is open. Remove it or check to see if the console object is defined before using it.

Comment: It works, you just need to open the Console in Developer Tools while the script's running.