# Are there any down sides to using console.log in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to know if there are any down sides to leaving `console.log` in my JavaScript functions as debug.

JavaScript:

```
var debugMSG = "DEBUG: "
var debugFStart = debugMSG + "Starting Function. Name; "
var debugFFinish = debugMSG + "Ending Function. Name; "

function myFunction1() {
      console.log(debugFStart + "myFunction1()")
      alert("Function 1 is being used!")
      console.log(debugFFinish + "myFunction1()")
}
function myFunction2() {
      console.log(debugFStart + "myFunction2()")
      alert("Function 2 is being used!")
      console.log(debugFFinish + "myFunction2()")
}
```

Would it be bad in any way to leave this code inside of my Websites Files when i upload it?

Comment: I see no harm , better than debugging with alert

Comment: Well it means anyone can open the console and see the messages, also depending on the browser you support some do not support `console` nor `console.log`.

Comment: Browser support is a good point.

Comment: Yes remember tht not all browser support console.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log` is a development tool - it has nothing to do with your app's functionality, and as such it shouldn't be deployed to production.

Remember, **the more code you have, the bigger chances of introducing bugs**. Therefore you should be as concise with it as possible (*but not more, to paraphrase Einstein ;)* ) For example in this case you have to remember to account for the browser to not have `console` object implemented. In that case your `console.log` construction *will* cause an error. And yes, you can account for that, conditionally make some mock object, but hey, you've just made your app more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

http://caniuse.com/#search=console

> IE8/9 : Only supports console functions when developer tools are open, otherwise the console object is undefined and any calls will throw errors.

I would suggest to add a definition to prevent those cases as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5967632/2558252).

I came across a website where the first script had a `console.log` in it and all the following scripts were failing because of that.

If you can use the full potential of the `console` object I would recommend
 those readings :

- [On Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api)
- [On Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes your code a lot less readable. That could be reduced to

```
function myFunction1() {
    alert("Function 1 is being used!")
}
function myFunction2() {
    alert("Function 2 is being used!")
}
```

Nice and simple.

If you need *logging*, use a logger (`console.log()` being a simple logger).

If you need *debugging*, use the [*debugger*](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers support console.log. Old IE doesn't support console.log. So if you app/website still support those old browsers better remove the console log or you can just create a fallback function to support it.

[Testing for console.log statements in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585351/testing-for-console-log-statements-in-ie)