# Access variable from outside of the function in jQuery

Tags: scope, javascript

Please see my exaple:

```
var AbcVar = "abc";

function Abc(AbcVar){
  console.log(AbcVar);
}
```

It this wrong way to allowing function to access `external var`?

**Why is the output of  `console.log` `undefined`?**

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer

Comment: Simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ph4tf/1/

Comment: This question as posed has nothing to do with jQuery, only JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's time to meet Mr. Scoping.

Plainly speaking, scoping is an encapsulation of variables (note that in javascript, functions are also variables.) Now, in the imaginary language I just made up, the `{` character starts a scope and `}` ends it, variables are defined with simple equality (`x = 42` for example):

```
{                                                                    |
    x = 42;                                                          |
    {                                           |                    |
        y = "I'm in an inner scope!";           |                    |
        x == 42; //true                         |                    |
        {                                  |    |                    |
            x == 42;                       |    |                    |
            y == "I'm in an inner scope!"; |    |                    |
                                           | x, y, z are defined     |
            z = "pyramid time!";           |    |                    |
            y = y + "...not";              |    | x, y are defined   | x is defined
        }                                  |    |                    |
        y == "I'm in an inner scope!...not";    |                    |
        //z is not defined                      |                    |
        x = 4;                                  |                    |
    }                                           |                    |
    x == 4;                                                          |
    //y is undefined                                                 |
    //z is undefined                                                 |
}                                                                    |
```

javascript has lexical scoping. Put simply, functions create a new scope:

```
var x = 42;
(funciton () {
    x === 42;
    var y = 5;
})();
//y is undefined
```

Now, there's an additional place where variables can be created, and that is in the function arguments. The two following functions behave the same (`arguments` is a pseudo-array containing the parameters passed into the function):

```
function parameterfull(a, b, c) {
    //do stuff with a, b, c
}

function parameterless() {
    var a = arguments[0], b = arguments[1], c = arguments[2];
    //do stuff with a, b, c
}
```

If you happen to not pass an argument, its value will be `undefined`.

Now, using your function and the above translation:

```
var AbcVar = "abc";

function Abc() {
    var AbcVar = arguments[0];
    console.log(AbcVar);
}
```

So now you see why `AbcVar` is (sometimes) `undefined` inside the function.

---

**tl;dr** The function parameter `AbcVar` is overriding the global variable `AbcVar`, and since you didn't pass a value to the function, it's `undefined` (but only inside of the function, the global `AbcVar` remains the same.)

Comment: I get the feeling `Mr. Scoping` has made many friends prior to his appearance today. Nicely put @Zirak

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function, `AbcVar` will refer to the *parameter* `AbcVar` of the function. If you don't pass any parameter, the value will be `undefined`.

The parameter *shadows* the variable in higher scope with the same name. *If* you want to access it, you have to remove or rename the parameter. That said, you should always prefer passing arguments to functions (where possible).

Comment: Or use `window.AbcVar` to access the top scope (probably the least preferable solution though).

Comment: @Felix Kling - thanks for details explanation, how can I pass argument to function? What is the different between parameter and argument? Is it the same?

Comment: @Tgr: Good point. If you access global variables, then it is actually good to access them with `window.` (more descriptive). But better if one avoids global variables at all.

Comment: @NewUser: You pass an argument like so: `func(someArgument)`. *Argument* and *parameter* are often used interchangeably but afaik, parameter is used when referring to the function definition, i.e. in your case `AbcVar` is a parameter, whereas argument refers to the actual value passed on runtime. I recommend to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).

Comment: @Felix Kling - I've got my self - Definitive Guide v6. How passing actual value to the function looks like? `function FunctionName("SomeValue")` ?

Answer (score 0):

if you run the function you've just created and pass it your `AbcVar`,

```
console.log(AbcVar);
```

it loggs `"abc"` as expected

Consider the following code

```
var AbcVar = "abc";

function logVariable(passedIn){
  console.log(passedIn);
}

logVariable(AbcVar);
```

which creates a variable, a function to log the value of the variable, and then passes the variable to the logger which loggs it in the console

If you notice two lines on your interactive console after you run your logger function: `abc` followed by `undefined`

[image: console result]

the first is the line printed when you call console.log() and the second is the value that logVariable returns after executing, which is `undefined` on success.

Comment: But not in Google Chrome (16).

Comment: @Alexander Wenzowski - thanks for taking the time to explain. Sadly, I still don't understand. Can you refer me to some documentation?

Comment: Why absolutely. Try the [javascript koans](http://blog.bittersweetryan.com/2011/08/learn-some-javascript-completely-on.html)

Comment: Or if that looks daunting try [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/#!/exercise/0)

Answer (score 0):

hi you can change this to

```
  var AbcVar = "abc";

        function Abc(bbb){

            console.log(AbcVar);

        }
```

you can access external global var,if you write inside function,it assume that like;

```
var AbcVar = "abc";

            function Abc(var AbcVar){

                console.log(AbcVar);

            }

 so inside funciton AbcVar is new vaiable  and null ,it shadow global AbcVar
```