# mvc3 google api Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'console' is undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps

I am using google maps api on my MVC3 website everything works perfect on Firefox but in Internet explorer I get a error message saying **Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'console' is undefined** . I have tried to fix this the code that is highlighted is **console.log("changed: " + $(object).attr('id'));** the portion of that code is

```
  $(document).bind("location_changed", function (event, object) {
    console.log("changed: " + $(object).attr('id'));

});
```

the Console is only causing problems with Internet Explorer . How can i fix that.. and i got the code from http://www.wimagguc.com/projects/jquery-latitude-longitude-picker-gmaps/

Comment: duplicate question. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725111/internet-explorer-console-is-not-defined-error or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 and lower does not have a console.  Some browsers do not have a console, so when using the console in javascript, it's a best practice to see if it exists first:

```
$(document).bind("location_changed", function (event, object) {
    if (window.console) {
        console.log("changed: " + $(object).attr('id'));
    }
});
```

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/690251/144496) for how to turn `console.log` into alerts when console is not defined.