# console.log() not working in visual studio 2012

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, console.log

I am trying log json data onto console using following code and I want to debug it using developers tool provided by IE.

My Code is

```
$.getJSON("s13.aspx", function (data3, textStatus3) {
                     console.log(textStatus3);}
```

But I am having error that console is undefined.

Why is it happening? How to solve it?

Comment: console.log working only if you open developer tool (F12) [MS-Documentation about](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#consolelogging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console` doesn't exist in IE unless the `console is actually open`

check this link for a detailed discussion:

[Internet Explorer: "console is not defined" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725111/internet-explorer-console-is-not-defined-error)

to check whether console is defined or not, you can do

```
if ('console' in window)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **if(window.console)** first.

```
if( window.console ){
   console.log('hi');
}else{
   alert('console not avaliable');
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console