# JavaScript abruptly returns or exits

Tags: javascript

When calling the below JavaScript method, the first alert is printed. Not even "Before return" alert is printed. Only if I do an F12, then the other alerts are shown. Please suggest!

```
function validateFPNotes() {
    var message = "";
    var notesId = document.getElementById('FANManagementForm:FANNotesTextIp');
    alert("validateFPNotes called and the notesid is :" + notesId);
    if (notesId != null) {
        alert("Not Null Block");
        var notesVal = trimString(notesId.value);
        alert("Notes Val:" + notesVal);
        window.console.log("validateFPNotes::notesId.value = " + notesId.value);
        alert("doc.getEletById(maxLengthNotes)" + document.getElementById(maxLengthNotes));
        var maxLength = document.getElementById(maxLengthNotes).value;
        alert("maxLength is:" + maxLength);
        if (notesVal != null && notesVal.length > maxLength) {
            message = message + replaceMaxLengthMessageTokens(document.getElementById(maxLengthExceedMessage).value, 'Notes', maxLength);
            alert("Message :" + message);
        } else {
            alert("Null Block");
            window.console.log("validateFPNotes::notesId.value = " + notesId.value);
        }
        if (message.length > 1) {
            alert(message);
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        alert("Null Block");
    }
    alert("Before return");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It means that you're having an error in between `if`. Did you check browser console for errors? I think error should be in `trimString()`

Comment: then am not even getting this alert: alert("Not Null Block");. Browser Console? am not sure of it.

Comment: To open console in Google Chrome: 

 Right Click -> inspect element- in the end you will see `Console` tab click on it and you will see some errors in **red**

Or 
Press `F12` as you know it :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless your code has encountered an error, in which case would prevent the rest of your code from running, you have a `return false;` `if (message.length > 1)`. If this is hit, your `alert("Before return")` would never be executed.

Comment: Should this mean, if (notesId != null) has something to do with?, as am not getting the next immediate alert, until I do an F12

Comment: I didn't run your code, but it could be. You have notesId declared as an object, not a value of that element. Did you do this intentionally or did you mean to use document.getElementById('FANManagementForm:FANNotesTextIp').value;?

Comment: Did you write your own trimString() function? I don't see it declared anywhere. If it's not declared, that could be your error.

Comment: trimString() is there used.

Comment: I see that it is being called, but that isn't a built in function. JavaScript uses .trim(). jQuery uses $.trim(). Also important to remember that the javascript .trim() isn't supported in IE8 and IE versions prior to IE8.

Comment: I can't see what is in your trimString() function because the declaration isn't in your code that is shown, as stated in the above comments, your error probably resides in that function.

Comment: trimString() I removed and still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the reason. Because windows.console is not available before F12-ing, the issue arose. I added this, and it worked fine, after adding this.

```
 if (window.console && window.console.log) {
                window.console.log("validateFanPermissionsNotes::notesId.value = "
                        + notesId.value);
            }
```

A simila instance here: [I.E. craches my JS script at first, then i press F12 and it works beaultifully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346091/i-e-craches-my-js-script-at-first-then-i-press-f12-and-it-works-beaultifully)