# hover on layer with hidden images doesnt work (IE9), works on firefox and chrome

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, positioning

See [description](http://pastebin.com/VaPqNh7Q) of the problem with all code:

SUMMARY: (basicaly making an imagemap)

- I have a div relatively positioned (i will call this the containter :) ), containing 1 image and a couple of div tags with their own image.
- The image directly under the container is the background image.
- The div under the container are absolutely positioned to be over the background image, the width and height is set to allow to call capture a "hover".
- The images under those divs are hidden at the start (the image dimensions are used for the width and height of their respective divs).
- When a hover occurs one one of those divs, the image it contains becomes visible)

==> the positioning and hiding showing is all done via jquery, see the pastebin link on top of the post for detailed information.

This works fine in chrome and firefox, but when tested on IE9, the hover doesn't work.
I have tried playing with the z-index of the divs, but at no avail.
Can somebody shed some light on this issue ?

See [description](http://pastebin.com/VaPqNh7Q) of the problem with all code:

Thx!

Edit: Created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gupb3/) from the provided code:

Comment: which version of jquery is it?

Comment: Pasting a link to pastebin where you describe the question is not very helpful.  Better would either be a link to the page/site where this is happening, or else setting this up in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the console.info lines.

console only works with javascript debugger on.

See also: ['console' is undefined error for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer)

Comment: I know that's why i have following code at the top of all javascript files:

Comment: // because ie does not support console if not in debug...
if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {},info:function(){}};