# Internet Explorer 9 not posting AJAX post request (Revisited)

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Several similar issues have been raised around this issue but none seems to come close enough like post 'Internet Explorer 9 not posting AJAX post request' ([Internet Explorer 9 not posting AJAX post request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16193605/2740562)), unfortunately, there was no resolution provided (that worked).

Are there specific 'type' and/or 'dataType' that is required for jQuery Ajax on IE? I would rather use a POST than GET, my dataType is text (not json), and my data is a serialized form (all just like in the referenced post); I need to know if there's anyway this could possibly work on IE(9) - it works effortlessly in Chrome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there specific 'type' and/or 'dataType' that is required for jQuery Ajax on IE

Nope. they all work in all versions of IE (IE6+). Your problem is likely specific to your server/network/client environment. You should ask another question that is more specific to your problem so that we can help you solve it.