# javascript not working in IE with radio button onClick

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onclick, radio-button

I have some code which acts as a redirect and sets some values when a user clicks on a radio button. In chrome and firefox these scripts work perfectly however in IE nothing seems to happen at all.

HTML

```
<td>
    <input type='radio' id="order_type6" name='order_type' value="5"
        onClick="selectOrderType('1')">
    <label for="order_type6"><strong>Facility Employee</strong></label>
</td>
<td>
    <input type='radio' id="order_type7" name='order_type' value="5" 
        onClick="selectOrderType('1')">
    <label for="order_type7"><strong>Private Contract</strong></label>
</td>
```

JS function:

```
function selectOrderType(type)
{
    console.log(type);
   //replace '&load=1' with '&neworder=1'
    $location = window.location.href.replace(/&load\=1/,'&neworder=1#');
   //replace '#' at the end of the string with '' + $ordertype
    window.location.href = $location.replace(/#?$|&order_type\=\D?/,'&order_type='+type);
}
```

Comment: Remove the console.log - or press F12 to open the console. IE does not support console if it is not open

Comment: PS: What is the point of using the same type and the same value on the two radios?

Comment: jsFiddle ftw: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/KD7Mn/show/

Comment: this is only a small ex of the full code hence the same value there are many other values to be had. And as for console.log... u win! but y would that not work?

Comment: See my answer. It is just one of those things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the console.log - or press F12 to open the console.

IE does not support console if it is not open

['console' is undefined error for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer)

Or change to `window.console && console.log(type)`