# TypeScript: console is undefined in IE

Tags: typescript

For JavaScript I found the following solution for Internet Explorer to be able to deal with console.log without hitting F12.
['console' is undefined error for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer)

however when I use the following lines in Typescript I can't compile.

```
if (!console) console = {log: function() {}};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting an error because the object literal you wrote doesn't have all the same members as a regular `console`. Simplest fix would just be to type-assert as `any`:

```
if (!console) console = <any>{log: function() {}};
```

Obviously you'll need to not call anything off `console` other than `log`.

Comment: I had to use this in IE 9: 'try {
    console
} catch (e) {
    console = <any>{ log: function () { } };
}'

Comment: @beatoss you cannot check `if(!somethingNonExistent)` in the global context which is why you get the exception. Recommend you use `typeof` instead. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I find the easiest way to handle this is abstract the console...

```
class Logger {
    static log(message: string) {
        if (typeof window.console !== 'undefined') {
            window.console.log(message);
        }
    }
}

Logger.log("Works with the console and doesn't ever error");
```

This also opens up other possibilities, such as handling the no console scenario with a message window, or logging errors to your server or whatever else you might want to do over and above logging to a console - it also makes it easier to run your code in a windowless context!

Comment: In a windowless context, `window` will be undefined and you will get an error on `typeof window.console`

Comment: If you are using something other than a browser, you can check the console wherever it exists in that environment. On the whole though, it is only the browser environment were console comes and goes in such a whimsical way (i.e. whether the console is open or not).

Comment: E.g in nodejs console exists. But 'if (typeof window.console !== 'undefined') {' would throw an error since window does not exist and you just tried to reference a property on it

Comment: Why would you even check if you writing a NodeJS program?

Comment: You wouldn't *need* to check, but would happen if you reuse the code there. I though that is what you meant with "windowless context". I get the confusion now:
comes and goes in such a whimsical way (i.e. whether the console is open or not): Not true. Irrespective of whether you have it open or not, it is (always) there on supported browsers, absent on old :)

Comment: I personally wouldn't reuse the logger - I'd use the strategy pattern to supply a logger appropriate to the environment. The code would depend on the abstract logger and not on `console`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at console.js.  It handles console logging in all browers, and more.  In order to compile with typescript, you will need to define console.log in a console.d.ts module definition, and then reference the d.ts file wherever you use console.log.

Answer (score 0):

The only operator valid on an undefined variable when in the global context is `typeof`. So I recommend the following code snippet:

```
if (typeof console == "undefined" || typeof console.log == "undefined") 
    console = <any>{ log: function () { } };
```