# Web Essentials 2013 has broken fix to console for typescript

Tags: typescript, web-essentials

We have been using TypeScript for a while and specifically this line to overcome IE's issue with the Console.

```
if (typeof console == "undefined" || typeof console.log == "undefined") var console = <any>{ log: function () { } };
```

However I upgraded my Web Essentials version recently to the latest, 1.85, and now I am getting the error on this line of code that has not changed.

```
Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'console' must be of type 'Console', but here has type 'any'.
```

I did try this page [TypeScript: console is undefined in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035274/typescript-console-is-undefined-in-ie) but I get errors trying to redefine window.console on some of the solutions.

Anyone else encountered this and what did they do about it?

Answer (score 0):

That error is correct. Your code should be :

```
if (typeof console == "undefined" || typeof console.log == "undefined") 
    console = <any>{ log: function () { } };
```

since `var console` is already defined in lib.d.ts

Comment: It ends up that Typescript has become aware of the Console object, so the solution we used was to do the same line but with this minor change:  `if (typeof console == "undefined" || typeof console.log == "undefined") var console = <Console>{ log: function () { } };` replacing **any** with **Console**