# Internet explorer open developer tools fixes script - WEIRD

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, compatibility

I am trying to understand WTF is going with Internet Explore 9, this no mean feat in itself.
I thought the problem was due to browser comparability issues but now I am unsure.

On the staging  server I have set the header to Header set X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge, but it is having no effect.

For example, If I reset the browser, and then open the URL:

http://www.45sound.com/shows/259-heathers-trinity-college-dublin-18-9-2012

Clicking on the timeline, does not move the nob or change the video.

HOWEVER, If I open developer tools, clicking F12, then close it, without reloading the page, it works perfectly...

Is this a loading issue, does anyone know what is going on?  I am unsure why this action has an effect on the javascript.

Any help at all would be really great.

Comment: Do you have `console.log` statements in your code? Afaik in IE you need to open the devtools to create the `console` object

Comment: Yes I do! Let me check it out....Thanks a million man you are a legend.

Comment: If you enable _Display a notification about every script error_ in _Internet Options_ -> _Advanced_ you find out quicker about such errors. The downside is that you then will be notified about every developer's script errors on any website...

Comment: Cool, thanks guys.  @Bergi, if you put than in as an answer I will accept it.  Really saved me, thought I was going mental....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like your code has problems with the weird implementation of the `console` object in IE - it does create the object only if the devtools are open. See also

- [Does IE9 support console.log, and is it a real function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5472938/1048572)
- [What happened to console.log in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8)
- ['console' is undefined error for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3326650/1048572)
- What the Head Said: [Internet Explorer 9′s problematic console object](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2011/04/internet-explorer-9s-problematic-console-object)

Comment: IE hurts my head! Thanks for this info I just spent the last two hours wondering why my javascript wasn't working... IE i hate you