# this.elem.prop is not a function

Tags: jquery

I need to select all cities under states (eg. India) listed. I put a select all:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="selectall" /> Select All
```

Then the below error is appearing:

> this.elem.prop is not a function

This is my code:

```
jQuery('.selectall').click(function() {
    stop = false;
    jQuery(this).closest('div').nextAll().each( function() {
        elem = jQuery(this).find('input');
        console.log(elem);
        if (stop || elem.hasClass('selectall')) {
            stop = true;
            return;
        }
        else
            elem.prop("checked", true);
    });
});
```

Comment: what is your jquery version  ???

Comment: You'd benefit from indenting your code in a consistent fashion.

Comment: Keep in mind console.log is not supported by all browsers. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer. Better delete it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `prop()` method was only added in jQuery 1.6. In previous versions you should use `attr()`.

```
elem.attr("checked", true);
```

Note about other answers, `elem` is already a jQuery object as it was defined on this line: `elem = jQuery(this).find('input');`, therefore the `prop()` method would be available if the jQuery version supports it.

---

UPDATE

To toggle the checkbox, use this:

```
if (stop || elem.hasClass('selectall')) {
    stop = true;
    return;
}
else
    elem.prop("checked", !elem.is(':checked')); // toggle the checkbox
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JQuery version must be older than v1.6. See the following JQuery documentation link that states that the "prop" function was only added from v1.6 onwards.

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

So the solution to your problem is to use "attr" function instead of "prop".

Apparently, attr retrieves attributes (which are the initial String values of the HTML elements) and prop retrieves properties (which could be the DOM manipulated values and could be of any type such as string, boolean, etc). Read the following Stackoverflow link for more detailed explanation on the difference between the two.

[.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr?lq=1)