# TypeScript Doesn't Recognize Firebug's window.console.debug

Tags: firebug, typescript

What TypeScript definition do I need in order for the TypeScript compiler to recognize Firebug's

```
window.console.debug
```

It recognizes

```
window.console.log
```

Without any issues.  I can't find a Firebug-specific definitions file (and I'm not even sure what .js file I could generate a definition file from).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a interface for `Console` and reference the declaration.

```
// firebug.d.ts
interface Console {
  debug(message: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;
}
```

`Console` is the interface used by the core `lib.d.ts`.

(I don't know what specific parameters would be required for Firebug's `console.debug`, so you'll have to change the parameters I provided if they differ from `console.log`.)

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize it would be quite that easy!

Answer (score 5):

The console.debug method has been deprecated (since Gecko 5) so your best bet is to switch to console.log - which is also cross-browser. Double win!

It is worth noting that console.debug was only an alias for console.log anyway, so you won't lose anything by switching to console.log.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console

Answer (score 0):

Don't assume `console.log` is always defined.
It may not be in Internet Explorer unless you have debug tools open.

See ['console' is undefined error for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer)

And my question
[Redefine window.console with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819983/redefine-window-console-with-typescript)