# Redefine window.console with typescript

Tags: typescript

I had the following javascript in my error logging code, which defines `console.log` for [certain browsers where it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer4) (IE doesn't/didn't have it defined unless the debug tools are open).

```
if (typeof console == "undefined")
{
    window.console = { log: function (msg) { } };
}
```

The problem when trying to upgrade the js to Typescript is that `window.console` is defined as being of the `Console` interface type and since I'm not specifying everything it (obviously) doesn't compile.

```
interface Console {
    info(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;
    profile(reportName?: string): void;
    assert(test?: boolean, message?: string, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;
    msIsIndependentlyComposed(element: Element): boolean;
    clear(): void;
    dir(value?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;
    warn(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;
    error(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;
    log(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;
    profileEnd(): void;
}
```

How can tell it to ignore this interface and just let me redefine `window.console`.

My best effort guess doesn't work

```
window.console = { log: function (msg) { } } : any;
```

Comment: see it there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43788480/451495

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A shorter solution is to just use a *type assertion*:

```
window.console = <any>{ log: function (msg) { } };
```

And even use a lambda:

```
window.console = <any>{ log: () => { } };
```

Comment: thanks :-) I wish the language spec has said something like 'this is the most similar feature to casting' so I could have found this

Comment: Yeah. They used a different term because casting implies runtime support. I.e. actual conversion. Saying it is similar to casting would make people think that e.g it actually converts a string to a number. With assertion you are only asserting that you know better than the compiler inference

Comment: `console` is now a `readonly` property as of typescript 2 - so you have to do this instead `(<any>window).console = { log: () => { } };`

Comment: curious if you have any opinion on `console` now being readonly. seems a bit weird to me - especially considering there are legitimate reasons for needing to set it. I suppose it helps beginners with silly mistakes but I think it's an oversight

Answer (score 4):

The interface is going to force you to create all functions. If you try to override the interface, it will give you a `Duplicate Identifier` error. So, here's the full stub to save you time :)

```
window.console =
{
    info: (message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]) =>
    {
        // ...
    },

    profile: (reportName?: string) =>
    {
        // ...
    },

    assert: (test?: boolean, message?: string, ...optionalParams: any[]) =>
    {
        // ...
    },

    msIsIndependentlyComposed: (element: Element) =>
    {
         return false;
    },

    clear: () =>
    {
        // ...
    },

    dir: (value?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]) =>
    {
        // ...
    },

    warn: (message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]) =>
    {
        // ...
    },

    error: (message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]) =>
    {
        // ...
    },

    log: (message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]) =>
    {
        // ...
    },

    profileEnd: () => 
    {
        // ...
    },

    count: (countTitle?: string) => 
    {
        // ...
    },

    groupEnd: () => 
    {
        // ...
    },

    time: (timerName?: string) => 
    {
        // ...
    },

    timeEnd: (timerName?: string) =>
    {
        // ...
    },

    trace: () => 
    {
        // ...
    },

    group: (groupTitle?: string) => 
    {
        // ...
    },

    dirxml: (value: any) => 
    {
        // ...
    },

    debug: (message?: string, ...optionalParams: any[]) => 
    {
        // ...
    },

    groupCollapsed: (groupTitle?: string) => 
    {
        // ...
    },

    select: (element: Element) => 
    {
        // ...
    },
};
```

---

**Alternate Solution**

If you don't want to write out all methods, you can fool TypeScript like this.

```
var x: any = 
{
    log: (msg) =>
    {
        //...
    }
};
window.console = <Console>x;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose I could do this  :-/

```
 var w:any = window;
 w.console = { log: function (msg) { } };
```

Comment: I added an alternate solution before I saw this message. Yes, yours works too :)