# Is there a way to have the console open automatically when I launch IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer always show F12 debugging to avoid console not defined in javascript ?
Is there a command-line arg ? That's sounds realistic.

I like to have the console always open while debugging for other reason, too.

Comment: Wrong problem to solve.. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer

Comment: Do you mean that you want your own copy of IE to always show the console? (You're not talking about making it happen for _other_ users, are you?)

Comment: @karthikr Nope that's exactly my problem... Just want to have it always open while debugging

Comment: @nnnnnn this make no sense

Comment: If someone changed your title, you can change it back. That being said, what's the problem with just pressing F12? You only have to press it once, right after you open IE.

Comment: every time... add this together. No its a little bit annoying.

Comment: The number of keypresses needed to write this question could've instead opened the console for you more than three-hundred times... Anyway, you might get a better response if you removed the part about avoiding the console not defined issue and just said "Is there a way to have the console open automatically when I launch IE?"

Comment: I would rather open console and refresh the page, than figure out how to keep console on all the time

Comment: I agree with @MR.ABC  While I'm debugging, I'd prefer the console open automatically when I bring IE up.  Saves me time, since I need the console every time I run the code.