# Issues with MaxMind GeoIP and government users using Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, geoip, netsuite, maxmind

I'm currently working on a rather complicated eCommerce site that is running on NetSuite. The core of NetSuite relies heavily on Javascript and I have implemented a fair amount of custom Javascript myself.

Most recently, I've implemented some code using Maxmind's GeoIP database to determine a user's location and take actions based on that location. The idea is to block certain countries from purchasing items, redirecting them to a country-specific page and notifying them that there is a distributor available in their country. (I know this is probably not the best way to do things, but these decisions, for a variety of reasons, are not up to me).

So, here's what I have going on. When the page loads, it runs the Maxmind script to determine the user's location and sets a cookie so I don't have to keep prompting for their location:

```
var geoCheck = (function () {

    var location = getCookie("country");

    var onSuccess = function (geoipResponse) {
        country_code = geoipResponse.country.iso_code;

        if (!geoipResponse.country.iso_code) {
            country_code = "US";
        }
        setCookie("country",country_code,365);

        return;
    };

    var onError = function (error) {
        country_code = "US";
    };

    if (location != null && location != "") {
        return function() {
            country_code = location;
        }
    } else {
        return function () {
            geoip2.country( onSuccess, onError );
        };
    }
}());
```

Then, when the user clicks the "Add to Cart" button, this function gets run to determine if the user is browsing from one of our restricted countries:

```
function countryCheck() {
    if (country_code) {
        switch (country_code) {
            case 'CN':
                /*redirect stuff*/
                return false;
            case 'TW':
                /*redirect stuff*/
                return false;
            /*...and so on for about 6 countries total...*/
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**THE PROBLEM:** Since I implemented this code, the client has consistently been fielding calls from government users using Internet Explorer saying that they can't add items to their cart. I had previously been using the GeoLite database and never had these issues before. It has only been since I implemented the code above.

I know this is a long, involved thread, but this one has got me stumped, so any help provided would be much appreciated. All the scenarios I can come up with for this not to work can be debunked almost immediately based on the previous implementation and other factors:

1. **Government computers blocking Javascript?**

   - Debunked because: It should have worked with the GeoLite solution and even before that because already relies heavily on Javascript for core functionality and doesn't provide many (if any) fallbacks.
2. **Government computers blocking cookies?**

   - Debunked because: The code doesn't really rely on the cookie to work. It is only set up as a convenience so I don't have to keep prompting the user for their location
3. **Government computers blocking W3C geolocation?** (a new feature of the new version of GeoIP):

   - Debunked because: If the W3C location fails, it should fallback on the Maxmind database, which was again used in my previous (working) solution.

Again, **I know this is a long thread**, but does anybody have any bright ideas of things to try? Any help provided would be MUCH appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea what version of Internet Explorer these users are using?

Comment: It is not safe to perform redirection or filtering in client site using javascript. It is very easy to be overwritten as the codes are visible. It is advisable to use server side scripting such as PHP for this purpose.

Comment: @oschwald: Unfortunately, no. I haven't been able to speak directly with the people having the problems. And even I could, these are the kinds of people who don't realize that they have Javascript disabled, so asking them to find out what version of Explorer they're using might be a little much for them.

Comment: @MichaelC.: Believe me, I'm right there with you. With the implementation of NetSuite (which is notoriously behind the times--I'm still nesting tables...), a lot of these choices have been made for me and Javascript is my only option at this point. We know that we'll never fully stop the customers in these countries, but we're trying our best to slow them down. I am packing and obfuscating the relevant redirection code (which I know can be decrypted), but that's where I've landed after 6 years of working on this site. I would love to implement a server-side solution, but that's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I had left an errant:

```
console.log();
```

Which causes IE to break. Using [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer), I added:

```
if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}};
```