# Console is undefined in IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, console

I made this jQuery script for selecting a color in proces that I made. Now I am testing my script in IE8 and I cannot select colors there anymore.

IE gave me an error that says: 'console is undefined'.

It says the problem is on line 101 in my script and that's this line:

```
console.log(num);
```

I founded other articles on stackoverflow (for example this one: ['console' is undefined error for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer)) that describing and fixing this problem, but I cannot get it work.

Can someone help me with this?

My script:

```
// Custom Select box
enableSelectBoxes();

// Custom select box function
function enableSelectBoxes(){
    $('div#color_scheme').each(function(){
        if($(this).children('span.selected').html() == '')
            $(this).children('span.selected').html($(this).children('div#colors').children('div#colors span:first').html());

        $(this).find('#colors span').click(function() {

            var num = $(this).data('selnum');

            if (!num) {
                num = $.trim($(this).html());
                console.log(num);
                $(this).data('selnum', num);
            }

            var oldSel = $('#colors span.selected_color');
            oldSel.removeClass('selected_color').empty().html(oldSel.data('selnum'));

            //remember the bg color
            var bgColor = $(this).css('background');

            if($(this).hasClass('color_none')) {
                $(this).addClass('selected_color').html(
                num + '<div class="this_color"><div class="color_example">Color value</div><input type="submit" name="submit_color" value="Selecteer"/></div>');
            }
            else {
                $(this).addClass('selected_color').html(
                num + '<div class="this_color"><div class="color_example">Color value</div><input type="submit" name="submit_color" value="Selecteer kleur"/></div>');
            }

            $('[name=submit_color]').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });

            $(".color_example").html($(this).attr('value'));

            //set the bgColor
            $(".color_example").css({
                background : bgColor
            });

            $("#color_field").attr('value',$(this).attr('value'));

        });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Basically, you have to open your console in IE8 or use any shim to handle it: `if(!window.console) window.console = {log:$.noop}`

Comment: Why did the solution given in the other question not work? You don't have it anywhere in the code.

Comment: IE8/9 do not define the `console` object unless/until Dev tools window is opened. See the dups for more info.

Comment: @Juhana I putted the if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}}; in my header

Answer (score 3):

Just add this to the top of your script:

```
if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}};
```

Let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: I placed the code at the top, and now there is nog error window anymore but my code doesn't work. Normally when I click on a color my scripts ensures that the color popups and then you can submit/click on it. But when I click now on a color nothing is happening. So I think I need to do something with my script?